# Finding the first 5 terms of the Maclaurin Series of $\frac{\sin x}{e^x}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

**Question**.

Find the first 5 terms of the Maclaurin Series of $\frac{\sin x}{e^x}$.

---

I'm trying to find it using division. Is there possibly a shorter way because every time I try to do it, I get the wrong answer:
$$
x-2x^3/3+\cdots$$

I don't really like polynomial long division.

This is how I set it up:
$$
\frac{x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7!+\cdots}{  1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + x^4/4!+\cdots}
$$

I'm still getting the same answer.

Comment: Either you divide, or you compute the series by computing the derivatives of $\sin x/e^x$ directly. The series does not start like you say it does, so your computation is wrong. In any case, "I don't really like polynomial long division" is not exactly motivation...

Comment: I've tried long division and that's the answer I get.

Comment: Well, you are doing it wrong, then! The series for that function starts $x - x^2 + x^3/3 + \cdots$ By the way, why do you think the result you get is *weird*?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: Because it's not the right answer.

Comment: Oh. You could probably edit the body of the question to replace *weird* by *wrong*, which is much more clear :)

Comment: In your setup you divide $\frac{e^x}{\sin{x}}$...

Comment: How did you get your answer Mariano Suárez-Alvarez?

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid division by writing $$\frac{\sin x}{e^x}=e^{-x} \sin x.$$ Multiply the series for $e^{-x}$ and $\sin x$ together to get the result.

Comment: Does that *really* save work?

Comment: @Theo: Since both the series for $\sin x$ and for $e^{-x}$ are pretty easy, I would say it kind of does...

Comment: For general $f(x)/g(x)$, this probably isn't much savings. But since we happen to know the series for $1/g(x)$ here, yeah, I think it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the first two terms:

$x - \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^5}{5!} - \dfrac{x^7}{7!} + \cdots$

$=x\left(1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!}+ \dfrac{x^5}{5!}+ \dfrac{x^6}{6!}\cdots\right) -x^2 -\dfrac{2x^3}{3}-\dfrac{x^4}{6}-\dfrac{x^5}{30}-\dfrac{x^6}{120}-\dfrac{x^7}{5040}-\cdots$

$= (x-x^2)\left(1 + x + \dfrac{x^2}{2!} + \dfrac{x^3}{3!} + \dfrac{x^4}{4!}+ \dfrac{x^5}{5!}+ \dfrac{x^6}{6!}\cdots\right) +\dfrac{x^3}{3}+\dfrac{x^4}{3}+\dfrac{2x^5}{15}+\dfrac{x^6}{30}+\dfrac{17x^7}{2520}+\cdots$

and you can continue from there, taking the first term of the residual of the second part as the next term to put into the multiplication in the first part.

Answer (score 1):

First off, $\sin(x)/e^x = Im(e^{(i-1)x})$ so the desired series is:
$$0+(-1)x^1/1!+(-2)x^2/2!+(-1+3)x^3/3!+(-4+4)x^4/4! + ...$$
So it looks to me like you're going to have to go to 6th order to get the first five nonzero terms, depending on what they mean by "terms". Now as to doing the division,
$$(x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7!) / (1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + x^4/4!)$$
The first result is $x$. So you multiply the $e^x$ by $x$ and subtract. The remainder is:
$$-x^2-(1/3!+1/2!)x^3 - x^4/4!+(1/5!-1/4!)x^5...$$
So the next term is $-x^2$. Continue on with this...

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\ $ It's the imaginary part of an expression, and every coefficient of $\rm\:x^{4\:n}\:$ is zero by [multisection / symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25674/given-an-exponential-generating-function-is-it-possible-to-isolate-only-the-even/25678#25678), so you need only compute it up to $\rm\:x^3\:.$

Answer (score 0):

By the Euler formula
$$
\textrm{e}^{\textrm{i}x}=\cos x+\textrm{}\sin x,
$$
we find the relation
$$
\sin x=\frac{\textrm{e}^{\textrm{i}x}-\textrm{e}^{-\textrm{i}x}}{2\textrm{i}}.
$$
Hence
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\sin x}{\textrm{e}^x}=\frac{\textrm{e}^{(\textrm{i}-1)x}-\textrm{e}^{-(\textrm{i}+1)x}}{2\textrm{i}}
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(\textrm{i}-1)^k-(-1)^k(\textrm{i}+1)^k}{2\textrm{i}}\frac{x^k}{k!}.
\end{equation*}
Then one can derive any terms in the series expansion at $x=0$ of the function $\frac{\sin x}{\textrm{e}^x}$.