# Finding the first 4 terms of a Maclaurin Series using division

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

Related question: [Finding the first 5 terms of a Maclaurin Series using division?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29416/finding-the-first-5-terms-of-a-maclaurin-series-using-division)

Hello, I'm having trouble finding the first four terms of the Maclaurin series for the following function (using long division):
$$ {\mathrm{tan} ^{-1} x \over 1+x} $$

It is already established that $\mathrm{tan} ^{-1} x = x - {x^{3} \over 3} + {x^{5} \over 5} - {x^{7} \over 7} + {x^{9} \over 9} - \cdots$ , so dividing this by $1+x$ gives me

$$ x - x^{2} + {2 \over 3} x^{3} - {2 \over 3} x^{4} + {13 \over 15} x^{5} - \cdots $$

But the book expects the following answer:

$$ x + x^{2} - {x^{3} \over 3} + {x^{4} \over 3} - \cdots $$

which isn't even remotely close to my current result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is correct, perhaps you misread the intended question or they mistyped the question.

Comment: @BenDoyle Thanks!