# Why must a function have to have even and odd parts

Tags: functions

For a function $f(x)$, it was given here with [derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/how-do-i-divide-a-function-into-even-and-odd-sections) that it has $E(x)$ as even part and $O(x)$ as odd part,

$$f(x)=E(x)+O(x)$$

why does this have to be always true? What is the proof?

Comment: The proof is in the derivation: you define those functions $f_e$ and $f_o$, check that they are respectively even and odd, and check that $f=f_e+f_o$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If our function takes values in a ring in which $2$ has an inverse, we can always write:

$$f(x)=\underbrace{\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}}_{E(x)}+\underbrace{\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}}_{O(x)}$$

Comment: I love this trick. It can help a lot with simplifying proofs in some situations.

Comment: to remember how this works: given $f$, what is the laziest way to make an even function out of it? we just take $f(x) + f(-x)$. and the same sort of thing for odd, take $f(x) - f(-x)$. then we see that $2f(x) = (f(x) + f(-x)) + (f(x) - f(-x))$

Comment: only caveat is that $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ must be defined

Comment: @Jared Sorry I didn't get the proof. I wanted to ask whether all functions are equal to sum of even and odd functions of themselves. If so, how?

Comment: @Prabhpreet: Notice how in the above equation, the part labeled $E(x)$ is an even function: replacing $x$ with $-x$ doesn't change the expression at all.  Similarly, the part labeled $O(x)$ is an odd function because replacing $x$ with $-x$ changes the sign of the expression.  Now, also notice that by combining fractions, the RHS is just $f(x)$.  So we've shown that $f(x)$ is indeed the sum of an even function and an odd function.