# Do functions over a ring have an odd and an even part?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, even-and-odd-functions

All functions $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be decomposed into an even and an odd part $f(x)=E(x)+O(x)$.

The proof I see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/460058/why-must-a-function-have-to-have-even-and-odd-parts), and on Wikipedia requires $2$ to have an inverse, however I want to know if this property is true of functions in a ring.

For a ring $R$ for every function $f(x):R\to R$, can I find even and odd functions $E(x)$ and $O(x)$ such that $f(x)=E(x)+O(x)$?

Using a similar method to the ordinary proof I can find that $2E(x)$ and $2O(x)$ are defined uniquely by $f$, but this only shows that $2f$ has a decomposition into an even and an odd part.
Because $2$ does not necessarily have an inverse, I'm not certain how to solve this.

I think that a decomposition seems possible, but it would not necessarily be unique?

Comment: The characteristic $2$ problem is real. Saying that a function is Even over a field of characteristic $2$ says nothing.  We always have $F(x)=F(x)$, after all.  So, sure.  You have a decomposition of the form you want, but it has no content.

Comment: @lulu I hadn't realised all functions are even over a field of characteristic 2. But if the ring is not of characteristic 2 does an even+odd decomposition exist?

Comment: Well, if the field is not characteristic $2$ then you can divide by $2$, so the usual argument works.

Comment: I'm only thinking of fields, I should stress.  Not sure what happens in a more general ring.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not always possible to find such a decomposition.

If $f(x)=E(x)+O(x)$ where $E$ is even and $O$ is odd, then $f(x)+f(-x)=2E(x)$ is always divisible by $2$.  So for instance if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ then this is not possible for any function with $f(1)=0$ and $f(-1)=1$.

On the other hand, if $2=0$ in $R$, then *every* function is both even and odd, so such decompositions are not unique (assuming $R$ has more than one element).