# Constant solutions of $\cfrac{dy}{dx} = \cfrac{x^{3}-x}{1+e^{x}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Consider the differential equation
$\cfrac{dy}{dx} = \cfrac{x^{3}-x}{1+e^{x}}$. How to find constant solution $y(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}y(x),$ where $y(x)$ is the solution such that $y(0) = \cfrac{1}{2}.$
I know if $y$ is a constant solution, then $\cfrac{dy}{dx} = 0$, which implies
$$x^{3} - x=0~~\implies x=0,1,-1. $$ Now, how can I show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty}y(x)=0~$ such that $y(0) = \cfrac{1}{2}.$

Comment: But here how can I find exact solution?

Comment: That's easy, is just $y(x) = \displaystyle \frac12 + \int_0^x \frac{t^3-t}{1+e^t}dt$.

Comment: It's hardly obvious that $\int_0^\infty \frac{ t^3 - t }{1 + e^t} d t = -\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: And the above equation isn't even true, the integral is approximately 4.859. So something's off with the question as written.

Comment: As written the equation has no constant solutions, unless you meant to replace all of the $x$ with $y$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Ok thanks, that means the Professor asked wrong question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. If $x\to \infty$ the result is just $\frac{1}{120} \pi ^2 \left(7 \pi ^2-10\right) \sim 4.85973$ as you gave.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed, which would make for a nice question by itself (I mean, I've also found out that the anti-derivative is given by some polylogarithmic type functions, and the idea for the computation "should be" the trick where you multiply top and bottom by $e^{-x}$ and then take $y = e^{-x}+1$ and force polylogs into the reckoning).

Comment: There's also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684597/investigating-integrals-of-the-form-int-fracfxdx1ex?noredirect=1) @ClaudeLeibovici. All in all, a very fruitful day then.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
|\cfrac{x^{3}-x}{1+e^{x}}|\le |(x^{3}-x)e^{-x}|
$$

so we have

$$
-(x^{3}-x)e^{-x}\le \frac{dy}{dx}\le (x^{3}-x)e^{-x}
$$

and

$$
\int (x^{3}-x)e^{-x} dx = -e^{-x} \left(x^3+3 x^2+5 x+5\right)+C
$$

Comment: Ok, but from here we can only deduce that $y(x) \le \frac{1}{2}$.