# Express the function $f(x)= (1-\sin x)/(1+\sin x)$ as the sum of an even and odd function.

Tags: functions

Express the function **$f(x)= (1-\sin x)/(1+\sin x)$** as the sum of an even and odd function.

Comment: Next time please show us your efforts.

Comment: Multiply and divide by $(1 - \sin x)$

Comment: I'm having a difficult time with this problem. The professor didn't explain this in the class and I really need to have an example for this for the Final Exam. I do apologize, but would someone be able to solve this our for me. I'm very confused and have no direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I divide a function into even and odd sections?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/how-do-i-divide-a-function-into-even-and-odd-sections)

Comment: I know that f(x)=(1+sin^2x)/(cos^2x) - (2sinx)/cos^2x) and I know that for each f(x) I need to find the h(x) and g(x), for that f.

Comment: Would the final answer be **bold**f(x)=(1+sin^2x)/(cos^2x) - (2sinx)/cos^2x)**bold** or is there more to it. Also what are the steps that I needed to take to get to that answer because I feel like I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: The Q  cited in the comment from Milo Brandt and its  leading answer  is the general method of solution   for any given  f(x).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Given any $f(x),$ you have
$$f(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2},$$
where the first is even and the second is odd. In applying this one has to make sure the domains are OK, so that has to be checked for your example.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time with this problem. The professor didn't explain this in the class and I really need to have an example for this for the Final Exam. I do apologize, but would someone be able to solve this our for me. I'm very confused and have no direction.

Comment: @happyglad  Arturo Madigan's answer to the question mentioned by Milo Brandt in his comment to your question goes through the method to prove the formulas above for even and odd parts of any function.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)= \frac{1-\sin x}{1+\sin x} = \frac{(1-\sin x)^2}{(1+\sin x)\times (1-\sin x)} = \frac{1+\sin^2 x-2sinx}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}+\tan^2 x  -2 \tan x \sec x  = sec^2 x+\tan^2 x  -2 \tan x \sec x$

Let the even function be $sec^2 x+\tan^2 x $

Let the odd function be $-2 \tan x \sec x $

Because the parity of $\sec^2 x$ and  $\tan^2 x$ and $\tan x$ and $\sec x $, it is easy to verify the parity of the above functions.

Comment: perfect! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> **Hint:** In order to answer such questions the *systematic approach* provided by @coffeemath is very helpful,  since it  provides you  a method to *always* find the odd and even part of a function $f$ regardless of its shape.

You want to split the function $f$ into the sum of an even function $g$ and and odd function $h$
\begin{align*}
f(x)=g(x)+h(x)
\end{align*}

> Recall a function $g$ is *even* if $g(x)=g(-x)$.

If we put
\begin{align*}
g(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
we obtain 
\begin{align*}
g(-x)=\frac{f(-x)+f(x)}{2}=g(x)
\end{align*}

> Recall a function $h$ is *odd* if $h(x)=-h(-x)$.

If we put
\begin{align*}
h(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
-h(-x)=-\frac{f(-x)-f(x)}{2}=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}=h(x)
\end{align*}

> Putting all together results in
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x)+h(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}+\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}=f(x)
> \end{align*}
>   and we are done.

$$ $$

> **The even  part of $f(x)$**
>
> With the help of (1) we *systematically* find the even part
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)+f(-x)\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}+\frac{1-\sin(-x)}{1+\sin(-x)}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}+\frac{1+\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\left(1-\sin(x)\right)^2+\left(1+\sin(x)\right)^2}{1-\sin^2(x)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2+2\sin^2(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}\\
> &=\frac{1+\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> **The odd part of $f(x)$**
>
> Similarly with the help of (2) we find the odd part
>   \begin{align*}
> h(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\left(f(x)-f(-x)\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}-\frac{1-\sin(-x)}{1+\sin(-x)}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-\sin(x)}{1+\sin(x)}-\frac{1+\sin(x)}{1-\sin(x)}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\left(1-\sin(x)\right)^2-\left(1+\sin(x)\right)^2}{1-\sin^2(x)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{-4\sin(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)}\\
> &=-\frac{2\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\\
> \end{align*}

We conclude the representation by even and odd part of the function $f$ is
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{1+\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}-\frac{2\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}
\end{align*}