# Can this equation hold? uneven function plus unknown function

Tags: calculus

if $f(x)$ is even , $g(x)$ is odd, $h(x)$ is not even and not odd.

Is it possible that $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ ?

I tried playing with the functions, changing variables and even more... but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Does uneven function mean odd function, that is $-f(x)=f(-x)$?

Comment: or does it mean *not even*?

Comment: Does "uneven" mean "odd"?  If so, then any function $h(x)$ can be written as the sum of an even and an odd function so, yes.

Comment: Edited! I meant odd

Comment: Hint: Subtract $g(x)$ from both sides, and note that if $g(x)$ is odd, so is $-g(x)$. What can you say now?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/how-do-i-divide-a-function-into-even-and-odd-sections): **every** real-valued function on $\Bbb R$ is the sum of an even and an odd function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *every function* $h$ it is the case that
$$ h(x) = \underbrace{\tfrac12h(x)+\tfrac12h(-x)}_{f(x)} + \underbrace{\tfrac12h(x)-\tfrac12h(-x)}_{g(x)} $$
where the terms marked $f(x)$ constitute an even unction of $x$ and those marked $g(x)$ an odd one.

So you can get your desired situation by choosing an arbitrary neither-odd-nor-even function $h$ and then define $f$ and $g$ as above (and then negate $g$ if you want the *precise* equation in your question).