# Summing up the series $a_{3k}$ where $\log(1-x+x^2) = \sum a_k x^k$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series

If $\ln(1-x+x^2)  = a_1x+a_2x^2 + \cdots \text{ then } a_3+a_6+a_9+a_{12} + \cdots = $ ?

My approach is to write $1-x+x^2 = \frac{1+x^3}{1+x}$ then expanding the respective logarithms,I got a series (of coefficient) which is nothing but $\frac{2}{3}\ln 2$.But this approach took some time for me (I can't solved it during the test but after the test I solved it)... Any other quick method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Lemma:** Let $f(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ be a power series.  Then

$$\sum a_{3n} x^{3n} = \frac{f(x) + f(\omega x) + f(\omega^2 x)}{3}$$

where $\omega = e^{ \frac{2\pi i}{3} }$.

*Proof.*  Ignoring convergence it suffices to prove this for a single term, and then it boils down to the identity

$$\frac{1 + \omega^n + \omega^{2n}}{3} = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } 3 | n \\\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

This is a special case of the [discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform).  Applying the lemma, we readily obtain that the desired sum is

$$\frac{\ln 1 + \ln (1 - \omega + \omega^2) + \ln (1 - \omega^2 + \omega)}{3} = \frac{1}{3} \ln (2 \omega^2 \cdot 2 \omega) = \frac{2}{3} \ln 2$$

where we use the fact that $1 + \omega + \omega^2 = 0$.

Comment: This is exactly,how they have proved it ... yet I don't understand.May be since I don't know what is convergence or divergence of the series.

Comment: @Debanjan: how are you doing anything with power series without learning about convergence and divergence?  Anyway, try doing it with polynomials first.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Nice general method! Thanks!

Comment: A small remark (also related to DFT of course):
Just like an analytic
function can be split into an even and on odd part,
$f(z) = \frac12 (f(z)+f(-z)) + \frac12 (f(z)-f(-z))$,
whose power series contain only even and odd powers of $z$,
respectively, one can also
split it into three parts containing powers $z^{3k}$, $z^{3k+1}$ and
$z^{3k+2}$, respectively, by a similar trick where the square roots of
one ($\pm 1$) are replaced by the cube roots of one ($1$, $\omega$,
$\omega^2$): (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) $f(z) = \frac13 (f(z) + f(\omega z) + f(\omega^2 z))
+ \frac13 (f(z) + \omega^2 f(\omega z) + \omega f(\omega^2 z))
+ \frac13 (f(z) + \omega f(\omega z) + \omega^2 f(\omega^2 z))$.
If a function lacks terms of the form $z^{3k+2}$, then
it will have the symmetry property
$f(z) + \omega f(\omega z) + \omega^2 f(\omega^2 z) = 0$;
an example of such a function is the Airy function $\mathrm{Ai}(z)$.

Comment: (cont.)
The Airy function is a solution to $f''(z)=z f(z)$.
Substituting a power series ansatz into the ODE shows that each
coefficient determines the coefficients three steps further down the
series, and since $f''(0)=0$, the coefficient $a_2$ is zero, and this
forces all coefficients $a_{3k+2}$ to be zero.

Comment: And just after writing all that, I noticed Bill's answer, which of course refers to the same thing...

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan:This question is actually from the chapter Exponential and logarithmic series if you go by my syllabus.

Answer (score 4):

Qiaochu Yuan gives an excellent exposition of the general method. Sometimes in specific cases you can get the answer via some hands-on calculations as well, and expanding the logs as you mentioned can actually be done pretty quickly: using that $1 - x + x^2 = {1 + x^3 \over 1 + x}$ one gets that $\ln(1 - x + x^2) = \ln(1 + x^3) - \ln(1 + x)$. You now can use the fact that the sum of $a_3 + a_6 + ...$ is obtained by subtracting the corresponding sums for $\ln(1 + x^3)$ and $\ln(1 + x)$. Since the power series for $\ln(1 + x^3)$ only contains powers of $x^3$, the contribution to $a_3 + a_6 + ...$ coming from that term is what you get from plugging in $x = 1$, namely $\ln(2)$.

The power series of $\ln(1 + x)$ may be written as $-\sum_{n > 0} {(-x)^n \over n}$.
Taking every third term gives $-\sum_{n > 0}  {(-x)^{3n} \over 3n} = -{1 \over 3}\sum_{n > 0} {(-x^3)^n \over n}$. Note this series is again the series of $\ln(1 + x)$, but applied to $x^3$ in place of $x$. Plugging in $x = 1$ gives ${1 \over 3}\ln(2)$.

So the answer you want is $\ln(2) - {1 \over 3}\ln(2) = {2 \over 3}\ln(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

Generally one can employ evaluations at roots of unity to take arbitrary such **multisections** of power series. See my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-expi-t-costi-sint/3514#3514) and the links there for discussion and examples. Generally, if we let $\rm\:w\:$ denote a primitive $\rm n$'th root of unity, then the $\rm m$'th $\rm n$-section of a power series selects the linear progression of $\rm\: m + k\:n\:$ indexed terms, viz. if $\rm\ f\:(X)\ =\ a_0 + a_1 X + a_2 X^2 +\: \cdots\ $ then

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad a_{m}\ X^m + a_{m+n}\ X^{m+n} + a_{m+2n}\ X^{m+2n}\ +\: \cdots $

$\rm\quad\quad\displaystyle\ =\ \frac{1}n\: (\:f\:(X) + f\:(Xw)\ w^{-m} + f\:(X\:w^2)\ w^{-2m} +\:\cdots\: \:+\ f\:(X\:w^{n-1})\ w^{(1-n)\:m}\:) $

See Riordan's classic textbook "Combinatorial Identities" for many applications of  multisections.