# How to verify these series expansions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We know that $$ x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \cdots (-1)^n \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + \cdots = \log (1+x) $$ whenever $-1<x<1$. What can we say if $x=1$?

That is, does the series $$ 1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \cdots (-1)^n \frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots $$ converge to $\log 2$? If so, how to prove this fact rigorously?

And what about the behavior of the series $$ x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} + \frac{x^9}{9} - \cdots (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} + \cdots, $$
which converges to $\arctan x$ for $-1<x<1$, at the points $x = \pm 1$?

Comment: It's Abel's theorem. The $\arctan \pm1$ sum converges to $\pm \pi/4$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/convergence-for-log-2 and  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46378/do-these-series-converge-to-logarithms

Answer (score 2):

Daniel's comment already has the solution: since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n$$

converges (Leibniz series) and the power series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}n=f(x)$$

converges for $\,|x|<1\,$ to a function $\,f(x)\;$ , then [Abel's Theorem](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/abelthm.pdf) gives us

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}n$$

from here, the sum of the above series indeed is

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\log(1+x)=\log2\;$$ since, of course, $\,f(x)=\log(1+x)\;$

Comment: Abel's Theorem tells us that the alternating series at $x=1$ converges, but it doesn't tell us that $f$ is continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: @robjohn That's exactly what Abel's theorem tells us. (Radially continuous at least.)

Comment: Oh, yes it does, @robjohn: that is what's great (and what it is *in fact*) with this theorem. Well, in fact it says the power series is continuous at $\,1\,$ *from the left*. The theorem is easily generalizable for any $\,t\in\Bbb R\;$ , not necessariyl $\,r=1\,$ . For ease I'm changing the link I gave.

Comment: I apologize. I was thinking of [Dirichlet's Convergence Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), which is proved similarly (using Abel summation, or [summation by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts)). Indeed, [Abel's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x\lt1$
$$
\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}-\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}\gt0
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}-\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}\right)
=x^{2k-2}-x^{2k-1}\gt0
$$
Thus, as $x\to1^-$,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}-\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}\right)
$$
is a positive series, increasing termwise to
$$
f(1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k}\right)
$$
which converges. Thus, by dominated convergence,
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=f(1)
$$
The same argument works for
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{x^{4k-3}}{4k-3}-\frac{x^{4k-1}}{4k-1}\right)
$$