# evaluation of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate :

a.$$\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{4\cdot5}+\frac{1}{6\cdot7}+\cdots$$

For this I looked at

$$x+x^3+x^5+\cdots=\frac{x}{1-x^2} \text{ for }|x|<1$$

Integrating the above series from $0$ to $t$ yields

$$\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^4}{4}+\frac{t^6}{6}+\cdots=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x}{1-x^2} \, dx$$

Again integrating the series from $0$ to $1$ will give 
$$\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{4\cdot5}+\frac{1}{6\cdot7}+\cdots=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x}{1-x^2} \, dx\right) \, dt$$

But upon integration $\log(1-t^2) $ comes which is not defined at $t=1$

Comment: The integrand is undefined at $t=1$, but the improper integral exists nevertheless.

Comment: how so?? @RobertIsrael

Comment: This is a classical example of a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: $\log(1-t^2) = \log(1-t) + \log(1+t)$.  
$\int \log(1-t)\ dt = (1-t) (1 - \log(1-t)) + C$.
Note that $\lim_{t \to 1-} (1-t) \log(1-t) = 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Using $\displaystyle \frac1{n(n+1)}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$

$$\frac1{2\cdot3}+\frac1{4\cdot5}+\frac1{6\cdot7}+\cdots=\frac12-\frac13+\frac14-\frac15+\frac16-\frac17+\cdots$$

Now use [Convergence for log 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11757/convergence-for-log-2) or [Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ and its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594838/taylor-series-for-log1x-and-its-convergence)