# What is the value of $\frac {1}{2\cdot3} + \frac {1}{4\cdot 5} +\frac {1}{6\cdot 7} + \cdots $?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is value of $\dfrac {1}{2\cdot 3} + \dfrac {1}{4\cdot 5} +\dfrac {1}{6\cdot7} + \cdots  =?$

1) $\log \left( \dfrac 2e \right)$

2) $\log \left( \dfrac e2 \right)$

3) $\log \left( 2e \right)$

4) $e-1$

I know it converges but I am not getting how to solve

Comment: $$\frac 1{n(n+1)}=\frac 1n-\frac 1{n+1}$$ have you heard the term "telescopic"?

Comment: In $2.3$, is the $.$ a decimal point or multiplying?

Comment: @S.C.B. it's multiplying

Comment: @LOL I answered as if it was a decimal point. Make that a bit clear later on.

Comment: @polfosol no,never heard,I will be very thankful if somebody answer without using strange terms

Comment: @LOL Where did I use strange terms?

Comment: @S.C.B. never mind, but I didn't understand anything

Comment: @LOL Which part didn't you understand?

Comment: @MartinR hey,there is no **limit** in my question,it can't be _duplicate_

Comment: @LOL Martin R deleted his comment.

Comment: @LOL Also, a series is  a limit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52841/discussion-between-lol-and-s-c-b).

Comment: @LOL.: So what does $+ \ldots$ mean if not a limit? But that other question was different, that was an error on my part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636496/evaluation-of-series.

Comment: @MartinR you looks so active to mark questions **duplicate** you can see that [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636496/evaluation-of-series) (s)he is trying by **integration**

Comment: @LOL.: The other poster tried something (which did not work), and you did not show anything that you tried, but it is still a question about the same series. And if you look at the answer to the other question, that is essentially the same as the answer posted below.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, I did not copy lab's answer.

Comment: @S.C.B.: I did not claim that, and I apologize if I made that impression. – But (as I see it) it is a duplicate question.

Comment: @MartinR I know. So I didn't say "As Martin R seems to be saying...". I said just to avoid confusion, as I would hate for someone to misunderstand that. I did not mean that you either explicitly or implicitly claimed that. Yes, this does seem to be a duplicate according to the policies of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n+1-n}{n(n+1)}=\frac{n+1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{n}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
Note that your series, $$\dfrac {1}{2 \times 3} + \dfrac {1}{4 \times 5} +\dfrac {1}{6 \times 7} + \cdots=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\dots$$
Since $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots=\ln 2$$
This result is known, and is discussed as the [Alternating Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series) on Wikipedia. So since $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\dots=1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\dots \right)$$ the answer is $1-\ln 2$. So the answer to your question is $$1-\ln 2=\ln e-\ln 2=\ln \frac{e}{2}$$So the answer is $2)$

Comment: But answer needs to be in terms of "e" and "$\log$"

Comment: @LOL, see my edit.

Comment: There is no "e" :(

Comment: @LOL $\ln x =\log_{e}x$.

Comment: @LOL. instead of complaining about the formatting of an answer, I recommend you first try to understand the answer, and only afterwards judge whether or not it is effective.

Comment: Check my edit .

Comment: @LOL Is $\log$ the $\log_{10}$ or $\log_{e}$?

Comment: May be $\log_{10}$ otherwise it would be $\text{In}$

Comment: @LOL I answered and editted.

Answer (score 2):

> Herein we present a methodology that relies on only straightforward arithmetic and knowledge of Riemann sums.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

The general term in the series is $a_n=\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}$.

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N a_n&=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n\\\\
&=1-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2N+1}\frac1n-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac1n\right)\\\\
&=1-\sum_{n=N+1}^{2N+1}\frac1n\\\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac1{n+N}\\\\
&=1-\frac1N\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\frac{1}{1+n/N}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Recognizing the sum on the right-hand side of $(1)$ as the Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx=\log(2)$, we have

> $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^Na_n=1-\log(2)=\log(e/2)$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, just for fun:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2n(2n+1)} = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}\,dx &=& -\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\log(1-x^2)\,dx \\(IBP)\quad&=&\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot\frac{1-x}{1-x^2}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x}\,dx\\&=&1-\log 2=\color{red}{\log\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)}.\end{eqnarray*}$$