# Sumfunction of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n}}{(4n)!}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-n}}{4n}$.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, summation

Sumfunction of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n}}{4n!}$ and   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-n}}{4n}$.

The first one looks like the cosine hyperbolicus but the $4n!$ anoys me. I tried using $\cosh(z^2)$ or something in that form but that doesn't work, for the second problem i tried to find something in the form of log(1+z) but that did give me problems with the $(-1)^n$. usually if i try to find the sumfunction i go through this phase:

1) try to find sumfunctions which look alike
2) if one does not work, try to differentiate to find your solution!

Any hints for the first sum function, the second function will eventually work i think.

Comment: Is it $4 (n!)$ or $(4n)!$?

Comment: $(4n)!$ sorry i will edit that right away!

Comment: For the first, maybe try using that $f^{(4)} = f$, and solve an IVP? Note that $f(0) = 1, f'(0) = f''(0) = f'''(0) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is $\frac12 (\cos z + \cosh z)$. (Every second term will cancel when you expand.)

Comment: how did you come up with this? Did you just write out the first terms of the taylor series and tried to manipulate those, or did you write out the series where you started with in this form?

Comment: Suppose you were given the series for $\cosh z$. You recognize that it agrees with the series for $e^z$, except that every second term is missing, but since you can find the partner series $e^{-z}$ which is like $e^z$ but with the opposite sign on every second term, you can just average them to get what you want: $\cosh z= \frac12 (e^z + e^{-z})$. And it's the same idea here: you recognize that your series is like $\cosh z$ with every second term missing, and you know that $\cos z$ is a partner series with alternating signs.

Comment: For a more general method (say if you have every *third* term of a known series), see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11739/

Answer (score 2):

Since the second one is $\frac{1}{4} \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{s^k}{k}$ for $s =\frac{1}{z}$, it's just Maclaurin series expansion for $\frac{1}{4} \log \frac{1}{1-s}$ for $|s|<1$.

Comment: i got $\frac{1}{4} \log(1-\frac{1}{z^4})$ is that the same?

Comment: In the second sum? Where does 4 come from?

Comment: yeah, i know that $log(1+x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{n}z^{n+1}}{n+1}$ and i just chose $z = \frac{-1}{z^4}$

Comment: No, just set $\frac{1}{z} = s$, so you get $\sum_{k \geq 1}\frac{s^k}{k} = \log \frac{1}{1-s}$ iff $|s|<1$. $Finita$.

Comment: ...'cause it's just 4 in the denominator, right?

Comment: yeah, the $\frac{1}{4}$ comes from the denominator if you change the sum starting from 0 instead of one, you remove the 4 to get the preffered form in $\log(1+z)$

Comment: You can't 'change the sum starting from 0', because you can't divide by 0!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22011/discussion-between-kees-til-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n}}{(4n)!}\\
f'(z)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n-1}}{(4n-1)!}\\
f^{(2)}(z)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n-2}}{(4n-2)!}\\
f^{(3)}(z)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n-3}}{(4n-3)!}\\
f^{(4)}(z)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n-4}}{(4n-4)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{4n}}{(4n)!}=f(x)\\
\end{align}
Now note that \begin{align}
f(0)&=1\\
f'(0)&=0\\
f^{(2)}(0)&=0\\
f^{(3)}(0)&=0\\
\end{align}
Therefore we proceed to solve the following boundary condition differential equation $$f^{(4)}-f(x)=0$$
Taking a Laplace transform we obtain
$$s^4F(s)-s^3f(0)-s^2f'(0)-sf^{(2)}(0)-f^{(3)}(0)-F(s)=0$$
or $$F(s)=\frac{s^3}{s^4-1}=\frac14\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac14\frac{1}{s+1}+\frac12\frac{s}{s^2+1}$$ thus taking an inverse Laplace transform we obtain 
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{-z}}{4}+\frac{e^{z}}{4}+\frac12 \cos z =\frac12(\cos z + \cosh z)$$

Note: Stefan also mentioned this above.

The second was treated already.

Comment: second is wrong! $e^x = \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: @KeesTil Thanks ups I see, I did not pay enough attention to the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The first series can be approached with the discrete Fourier transform. Since
$$ f(n) = \frac{1}{4}\left(1^n+(-1)^n+i^n+(-i)^n\right)$$
is the indicator function of the integers being multiples of four, we have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{4n}}{(4n)!}=\sum_{n\equiv 0\pmod{4}}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac{1}{4}\left(e^x+e^{-x}+e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos x+\cosh x\right).$$
The second series is just:
$$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(1/z)^n}{n}=-\frac{1}{4}\log\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second sum use this this general result:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{nz^n},\;\;\;\; z\in\mathbb C\;.
$$
We immediately see that $|z|>1$, in order to have absolute convergence.

We recall first two results:

$\bullet\;\;$First:
$$
\log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{z^n}{n},\;\;\;\forall |z|<1
$$
$\bullet\;\;$Second:
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+z^{2^{n}}\right)=
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}z^{n}=\frac{1}{1-z},\;\;\;\forall |z|<1
$$
The last one can be proved, showing by induction that $\prod_{k=0}^{N}\left(1+z^{2^{k}}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{N+1}-1}z^{k}$.

Ok:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{nz^n}=&
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n\\
=&\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k+1}-
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}}_{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)}+
2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2k}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2k}\\
=&\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)+
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)^{k}\\
=&\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)+
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)+\cdots\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{z^{2^n}}\right)\\
=&\log\left(\prod_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{2^n}\right)\right)\\
=&\log\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)
\end{align*}