# What is the value of $e^{3i \pi /2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

When solving for the value, we know that $e^{\pi i}=-1$ .
I am confused as to what is the right answer when you evaluate this.I am getting two possible answers: $e^{3\pi i/2}$ = $(e^{\pi i})^{3/2}$ so this could be $(\sqrt{-1})^3=i^3=-i$ or it could be $\sqrt{(-1)^3}=\sqrt{-1}=i$. Which one is the correct answer, and where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula

Comment: In the complex world, exponents do not behave the same as in the so-called "real" world.

Comment: This is a similar error to believing that $(\sqrt{-1})^2 = \sqrt{(-1)^2}$.  In general $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ will be true for positive real values of $a$ and real exponents, but as soon as you let $a$ be negative or let $b,c$ be nonreal things can break.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

$$e^{3\pi i/2}:=\cos\frac{3\pi}2+i\sin\frac{3\pi}2=0+i\cdot(-1)=-i$$