# Exact sum of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to find the exact sum of the following series, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3-n}$.
The solution goes like this:

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^3-n}$

$= \frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n-1} +  \frac12\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} +\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$

$=\frac12\ln2 + \frac12(\ln2 -(1-\frac12)) + \ln2-1$

$= 2\ln2-\frac54$

I understand how to do the first step by partial fractions. But I did not understand the next step. Can you help me understand how these sums become $\ln$s?

Comment: Your title doesn't match with the question posted in the context body

Comment: that the maclaurin series of ln x

Comment: Your post will look  better and be easier to read is you use `$\ln$` instead of `$ln$`.  Similarly for `$\sin, \cos$` and so on.

Comment: I looked at the ln x Maclaurin series, it looks like I can solve this with them. Thanks for the advice about writing ln and. But I am not sure what kind of title would be relevant to the question, so if you have suggestions I can change it.

Comment: Oh I see, I forgot the change the series in the title from my last question, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the fact that$$x\in(-1,1]\implies\log(x+1)=x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^4}4-\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{\left(-\dfrac13\right)^n}{2n+1}=\dfrac1x\cdot\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$

where $x=\dfrac i{\sqrt3}$

$$S=2\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)=\ln\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}=\ln\dfrac{1+\dfrac i{\sqrt3}}{1-\dfrac i{\sqrt3}}=\ln\dfrac{\sqrt3+i}{\sqrt3-i}$$

As $\dfrac{\sqrt3+i}{\sqrt3-i}=\dfrac{\cot\pi/6+i}{\cot\pi/6-i}=e^{i\pi/3}$ using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

So the principal value of $S$ will be $\dfrac{i\pi}3$

Comment: I could not understand how to use this in my situation, this is probably too advanced for me, still, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @RüzgarAyan, I've followed the problem in the title

Comment: Yeah it is totally my fault, I am really sorry.