# Find $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(nx)}{n!}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

How could one find $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(nx)}{n!}}\,?$$

I tried to use Fourier series and integrals depending on a parameter to reduce the problem to a differential equation, but that didn't work.

Comment: $\cos(nx)$ is the real part of $e^{inx}$ which is the real part of $(e^{ix})^n$. The sum of $\frac{(e^{ix})^n}{n!}$ is easy to get so you just need to take the real part of that.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(nx)}{n!}}=$$

$$=\text{ real part of }\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(e^{ix})^n}{n!}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(e^{ix})^n}{n!}=e^{\cos x+i\sin x}=e^{\cos x}(\cos(\sin x)+i\sin(\sin x))$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but does there exist a method, that does not attract complex analysis?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n!}
=&\Re\left[\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(e^{ix})^n}{n!}\right]\\
=&\Re\left[e^{e^{ix}}\right]\\
=&\Re[e^{\cos x+i\sin x}]\\
=& e^{\cos x}\cdot\cos(\sin x)
\end{align*}