# Find modulus and argument of $\omega = {\frac {\sin (P + Q) + i (1 - \cos (P + Q))} {(\cos P + \cos Q) + i (\sin P - \sin Q) }} $

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

A past examination paper had the following question that I found somewhat difficult. I tried having a go at it but haven't come around with any possible double angle identities. How would one go about tackling it?

> Given:
>
> $$\omega = {\frac {\sin (P + Q) + i (1 - \cos (P + Q))} {(\cos P + \cos Q) + i (\sin P - \sin Q) }} $$
>
> To prove:
>
> $$|\omega| = \tan \frac {P + Q} {2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \arg(\omega) = Q $$

A guideline on how/ which identity to use would be greatly appreciated.

To give an idea how one would start it is by;

Proof:

$$|\omega| = {\frac {\sqrt{\sin^2 (P + Q) + (1 - \cos (P + Q))^2}} 
{\sqrt{(\cos P + \cos Q)^2 + (\sin P - \sin Q)^2 }}} $$

I'm still unsure about the above or how the square root come about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
N
& := \sin^2(P+Q) + (1-\cos(P+Q))^2 = \sin^2(P+Q) + \cos^2(P+Q) + 1 - 2\cos(P+Q) \\
& =  2 (1-\cos(P+Q))
= 2\cdot2\sin^2\frac{P+Q}{2}
= 4\sin^2\frac{P+Q}{2}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
D
& = \cos^2P +\cos^2Q + \sin^2P + \sin^2Q + 2(\cos P\cos Q - \sin P \sin Q) \\
&= 2 +2(\cos(P+Q))
= 2(1+\cos(P+Q)) = 4\cos^2\frac{P+Q}{2}
\end{align}

Now, $$|\omega| = \sqrt{\frac{N}{D}} = \tan\frac{P+Q}{2}$$

Comment: What about the proof of $ arg(\omega) = Q $ ?

arg (N) - arg (D)?

Comment: Yes! $$\arg(Nr) = \arctan \frac{1-\cos(P+Q)}{\sin(P+Q)} = \arctan\frac{2\sin^2(\frac{P+Q}{2})}{2\sin(\frac{P+Q}{2})\cos(\frac{P+Q}{2})} = \frac{P+Q}{2}$$ and $$\arg(Dr) = \arctan \frac{\sin P-\sin Q}{ \cos P + \cos Q} = \arctan \frac{\sin\frac{P -Q}{2}\cos\frac{P+Q}{2}}{\cos\frac{P+Q}{2}\cos\frac{P-Q}{2}} = \frac{P-Q}{2}$$ Thus, $$\arg(\omega) = \frac{P+Q}{2} - \frac{P-Q}{2} = Q$$

Answer (score 4):

You just need Pythagoras and compound angle formulae, and in particular identities for $\cos 2x$. The numerator surd simplifies to $$\sqrt{2\left(1-\cos(P+Q)\right)}=2\left|\sin\frac{P+Q}{2}\right|,$$while the denominator surd simplifies to $$\sqrt{2\left(1+\cos(P+Q)\right)}=2\left|\cos\frac{P+Q}{2}\right|.$$

Answer (score 2):

Using [Double Angle formula,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html)

$$N_r=\sin(P+Q)+i(1-\cos(P+Q))$$

$$=2\sin\dfrac{P+Q}2\cos\dfrac{P+Q}2+2i\sin^2\dfrac{P+Q}2$$

$$=2\sin\dfrac{P+Q}2\left(\cos\dfrac{P+Q}2+i\sin\dfrac{P+Q}2\right)=2\sin\dfrac{P+Q}2 e^{i(P+Q)/2}$$ using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),  $$D_r=\cos P+\cos Q+i(\sin P-\sin Q)$$
$$=2\cos\dfrac{P+Q}2\left(\cos\dfrac{P-Q}2+i\sin\dfrac{P-Q}2\right)=2\cos\dfrac{P+Q}2e^{i(P-Q)/2}$$

$$\implies \omega=\tan \frac {P + Q}2 e^{i Q}$$

$\displaystyle|\omega| = \left|\tan \dfrac {P + Q}2\right|=\begin{cases} \tan \dfrac {P + Q}2&\mbox{if } \tan \dfrac {P + Q}2\ge 0 \\ 
-\tan \dfrac {P + Q}2 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases} $

arg$(\omega)$ can be computed [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation)