# How to do this expression with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

$\frac{1}{2^{2+4i}}$, where i is the imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$. What is the value?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F((2)%5E(2%2B4i))) has the value. How to calculate it? Convert to exponential form.

Comment: Yes, but i want the deduction.

Comment: Please use MathJax notation

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) first and add context to your question. You must show some sort of working out to meet our site's standards.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

$$\dfrac1{2^{2+4i}}=\dfrac{16^{-i}}{2^2}=\dfrac{(e^{\ln16})^{-i}}4 $$

$$(e^{\ln16})^{-i}=e^{-i\ln16}=\cos(-\ln16)+i\sin(-\ln16)$$

$\cos(-A)=+\cos A,\sin(-A)=-\sin A$

Now $\ln16=\ln(2^4)=4\ln2$