# Finding smallest n satisfying $z^n$ is real and positive.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i$.
Find smallest positive integer $n$ such that $z^n$ is real and positive.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: write $z$ in polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Write $z$ in complex exponential form $\,r\,\mathrm e^{i\theta}$.

*Another hint*:

You'll need the linearisation formulæ:
$$\sin^2\theta=\tfrac12(1-\cos 2\theta),\qquad \cos^2\theta=\tfrac12(1+\cos 2\theta).$$

Comment: I have problem with finding the angle i know that it is $\frac{\pi}{8}$, but i don't know hot to show it.

Comment: I've added another hint.

Comment: Thank you, now i got it

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

By observation

If $2y=45^\circ,$

$$z=1+\cos2y+i\sin2y=2\cos^2y+2i\sin y\cos y=2\cos y(e^{iy})$$ using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

Answer (score 0):

For $\theta=\arg(z)$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(\theta)
&=\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z)}{\operatorname{Re}(z)}\\[3pt]
&=\sqrt2-1
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore, $\theta$ is in the first quadrant and
$$
\begin{align}
\tan(2\theta)
&=\frac{2\left(\sqrt2-1\right)}{1-\left(\sqrt2-1\right)^2}\\
&=1\\[3pt]
&=\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)
\end{align}
$$