# Sum of Series Question (image) - Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

The series $P$ and $Q$ are defined for $0<\theta<\pi$ as

$$P=1+\cos\theta+\cos2\theta+\cos3\theta+\ldots+\cos12\theta$$

$$Q=\sin\theta+\sin2\theta+\sin3\theta+\ldots+\sin12\theta$$

Show that $\displaystyle P+\mathrm iQ=\frac{\mathrm e^{6\mathrm i\theta}(\mathrm e^{\frac{13\mathrm i\theta}2}-\mathrm e^{-\frac{13\mathrm i\theta}2})}{\mathrm e^{\frac{\mathrm i\theta}2}-\mathrm e^{-\frac{\mathrm i\theta}2}}$.

We have

$$P=1+\cos\theta+\cos2\theta+\cos3\theta+\ldots+\cos12\theta$$

$$Q=\sin\theta+\sin2\theta+\sin3\theta+\ldots+\sin12\theta$$

So that

$$P+iQ=1+\mathrm e^{i\theta}+\mathrm e^{2i\theta}+\mathrm e^{3i\theta}+\ldots+\mathrm e^{11i\theta}+\mathrm e^{12i\theta}$$

Comment: which is in geometric  progression

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question so that it can be searched by others.

Comment: I've edited your question with MathJax. Please look through the [edit] to see if everything is alright as well as try to learn how to use MathJax from what I've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$=\dfrac{e^{i13\theta}-1}{e^{i\theta}-1}=\dfrac{e^{i13\theta/2}(e^{i13\theta/2}-e^{-i13\theta/2})}{ e^{i\theta/2}(e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2})}$$

Using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)
we can actually simplify further

$$2i\sin y=e^{iy}-e^{-iy}$$