# What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \root{2n+1} \of {-1} ?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

First of all, I'm sorry if this question has been already asked and answered, as far as I searched, I couldn't find such a question on this site. 
So, I've been thinking about the limit of the sequence $\left(\root{2n+1}\of{-1}\right)_{n\geq 0}$. Since the order of the root is odd for every $n$, this sequence, is obviously a constant sequence with the general term $a_n = -1$. So, from this follows that $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \root{2n+1}\of{-1} = -1 $$.
We can even do an $\epsilon-N$ proof to show this (and it's realy easy actually): $$ \forall \epsilon > 0 \hspace{0.5cm} \exists N \geq 0 \hspace{0.3cm} \text{s.t.} \hspace{0.3cm} \left|\root{2n+1}\of{-1}+1\right|<\epsilon \hspace{0.5cm} \forall n \geq N \\ \left|\root{2n+1}\of{-1} + 1\right| = \left|-1 + 1\right| = 0 < \epsilon \hspace{0.5cm} \forall n \geq 0 \\ N = 0 \ _\blacksquare $$.

However, if we use tehniques ussualy used for solving limits, we end up with a different result: 
$$ \begin{align*} 
\lim_{n\to\infty} \root{2n+1}\of{-1} &= \lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{1\over 2n+1} \\
&= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}-1\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over 2n+1}} \\ &= (-1)^0 \\ &= 1 \end{align*} $$.

What is wrong here? Why do the two methods give different results?

Edit: To make everything clear, I'm assuming the real root as defined by $\root n \of {} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for odd $n$ and treating this as a real-analysis problem. Also, it's pretty explicit from my question that I'm working with a sequence and not with a function. The limit only goes through natural values of $n$

Edit 2: I've figured it out. Thank you all for your answers esspecially to @Jack who pointed out the theorem I've been using $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n^{b_n}) = (\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n)^{(\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n)}$ is not true in general. I've consulted my textbook again and saw that I've missed the part where they said $a_n > 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Of course, we can think of this problem also from the viewpoint of functions and the fact that the function $(-1)^x$ is not continuous is another gap in using something like the above theorem. Thank you all again for being so kind and giving me so many answers.

Comment: The problem is that you need to pick a definition of what $\sqrt[n]{z}$ means for a complex number $z$. This function will have discontinuities.

Comment: Your problem is not well-defined. With positive real numbers, $a^{1/n}$ means **the** positive $n^{\rm th}$ root. But with a non-positive number, there are $n$ choices for an $n^{\rm th}$ root of $a$, and no privileged. one.

Comment: Why is $\sqrt[2n+1]{-1}=-1$ for every $n\ge 0$?

Comment: @0x539, I know the function will have discontinuities, but I'm talking about the sequence, the limit is with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, the definition I'm using for $\root n \of z$ is the principal root which is well defined on $\mathbb{R}$ for odd $n$. I'm approaching this limit from a real-analysis viewpoint

Comment: @Martin Argerami I'm assuming the principal root.

Comment: @Peter Foreman, can you direct me to some proof of this? My book only said that the two sequences need to be convergent.

Comment: @StefanOctavian: what book are you using?

Comment: @Jack My math schoolbook. It's rare chances you will know it unless you live in the same country as me. "Matematica Manual pentru clasa a XI-a" by Marius Burtea and Georgeta Burtea

Comment: I can't find a reference that clearly states $(-1)^0=1$.

Comment: https://www.carminis.ro/imagini/Manual-matematica-clasa-XI-M1.pdf

Comment: Yes, that is the book. I misread theorem 13 at page 133

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expression $\sqrt[2n+1]{-1}$ (for any nonnegative integers $n$) is defined to be, as you stated in the post, the unique real number $y$ such that $y^{n+1}=-1$. Since by your definition, $\sqrt[2n+1]{-1}=-1$, there is no doubt that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n+1]{-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)=-1.
$$

There is no problem for the limit itself.

What goes wrong here is in your second "method":

> if we use techniques usually used for solving limits, we end up with a different result: 
>   $$ \begin{align*} 
> \lim_{n\to\infty} \root{2n+1}\of{-1} 
> &= \lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{1\over 2n+1} \\
> &= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}-1\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over 2n+1}} \\ 
> &= (-1)^0 \\ &= 1 \end{align*} $$.

The following step is problematic:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{1\over 2n+1} 
= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}-1\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over 2n+1}}
$$

What you use here is 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n}^{b_n}=(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n)^{(\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n)} \tag{1}
$$
where $a_n=-1$ is the constant sequence and $b_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}$. But (1) is **NOT** true in general.

---

[Added]
In *real* analysis, one rarely writes expression like $a^b$ for $a\leq 0$ and arbitrary real number $b$, unless one *specifically* defines such expression for some particular $a$ and $b$. For instance, you define $(-1)^{1/n}$ for only $n$ being an odd positive integer and let $(-1)^{1/n}$ be the unique number $y$ such that $y^{n}=-1$. In such situation, $(-1)^{1/n}$ is nothing but the real number $-1$.

One definition for the expression $a^b$ with $a>0$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ is $e^{b\ln a}$. And one has the following statement

> Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a *positive* sequence of real numbers such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=a$. Assume in addition that $\{b_n\}$ is a real sequence with $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b$. Then
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^{b_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{b_n\ln a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{b\ln a}=a^b.
> $$

If one does want to consider the expression $a^b$ for negative real number $a$, then one would

- either stick to the definition for the some specific $a$ one has,
- or unavoidably talk about the complex logarithm. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases) Wikipedia article.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Can you tell me some conditions for which (1) is true or direct me to some resources?

Comment: @StefanOctavian: you are welcome. I have added a few words into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you know $$\root{2n+1}\of{-1}$$ is not just one number but $2n+1$ different numbers.

Thus the following limit is not even well-posed.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \root{2n+1}\of{-1} $$

Of course $-1$ is always included in the set of $2n+1^{st}$ roots of $-1$ so if you choose that root for every $2n+1$, then you may say that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \root{2n+1}\of{-1}=-1 $$

Comment: I'm assuming principal root

Comment: @stefanoctavian But the principal root does tend to one...

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant real root not principal root

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of looking at this.

The first is that you require the root to be real. In that case, both methods give -1. Because there is only one real root for any $2n+1$ and it is -1. So the 2nd line of your final 4 line derivation is wrong: the rhs is simply $\lim_{n\to\infty}-1=-1$.

The other way of looking at it is that we really need to work with complex numbers to figure out what is going on. In that case there are $2n+1$ roots, so you have to decide which one you are picking when you take the limit. They are all on the unit circle - are you familiar with the Argand diagram? If you pick the one with the smallest "argument" (ie angle to the positive real axis) each time, then you get +1 as the limit. If you pick the one with the largest angle each time, then you get -1 as the limit.

Incidentally, I do not understand your $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in this step:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (-1)^{1\over 2n+1}= \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}-1\right)^{\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over 2n+1}}$$

You seem to be using, that the function $a, b \mapsto a^b$ is continuous. But in real Analysis this function is only defined when $b = \frac1{m}$ for some integer $m$. Therefore you cannot interchange the limits.

(Of course you can define $a, b \mapsto a^b$ as a continuous function but then you need to use complex analysis and will run into the discontinuities I mentioned in my comment.)

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I'm explicitly talking about a sequence, not a function. The limit is only for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @StefanOctavian Yes, that's the thing: Interchanging the limits like $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^{\frac1{2n + 1}} = (-1)^{\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{2n+1}}$ is only valid if $x \mapsto (-1)^{x}$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Sequences are functions @StefanOctavian

Comment: @0x539 Sequences remain functions. You can use the rule that you used, only if the limit of the base sequence and the one of the power sequence exists *and* if the function $(-1)^x$ is continuous. This doesn't imply that sequences aren't functions.

Comment: @Bman72, sequences are a special type of functions: they are defined on some subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ usually $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{N^*}$. With sequences we can not talk about such things as being continuous.

Comment: @StefanOctavian, you are right sequences are a special type of functions. However, it is sometimes very insightful to look at a more general case and check how things behave there. gimusi's answer is very short, but covers the same argument as Jack or Carlos Esparza for example.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sqrt[2n+1]{-1}=y$

$y^{2n+1}=-1=e^{(2m+1)\pi i}$ where $m$ is any integer

$y=e^{(2m+1)\pi i/(2n+1)}$ where $0\le m\le 2n$

Using

[Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

$y$ will be real if $\pi$ divides $\dfrac{(2m+1)\pi}{2n+1}$

$\iff2n+1$ divides $2m+1$ which is possible if $m=n$

So, the only real value of $y$ is $-1$

Of course this is possible if $n$ remains an integer

Answer (score 0):

Let

- $x=\frac1n\to 0^+$
- $f(x)=(-1)^x $
- $g(x)=\frac x{2+x}\to 0$

then the property

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(g(x))=f(\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x))$$

doesn't hold necessarly since $f(x)$ is not continuous.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I'm explicitly talking about a sequence, not a function. The limit is only for $n \in \mathbb{N}$