# How to solve ${\rm Ln}({\rm cosecant}(z)) = {\rm Ln}(2) + iz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

$\newcommand{\Ln}{\operatorname{Ln}}$
$$\Ln(\csc(z)) = \Ln(2) + iz$$
I need to know what complex number $z$ is

Comment: I haven't tried it but you can write the cosecant as exponentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

$$\dfrac{\csc(z)}2=e^{iz}$$

If $e^{iz}=a,$

Using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

$2a=\dfrac{2i}{a-1/a}$ as $a\ne0$

$a^2-1=i$

$a^2=\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}$

Comment: You need to add the condition that the Ln on the left side and thus also the right side has imaginary part in $[-\pi,\pi]$, limiting the real part of $z$.