# How to simplify the ratio $1 - \cos2x + i\sin2x \over 1 + \cos2x - i\sin 2x$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

The ratio is as follows:

$$1 - \cos2x + i\sin2x \over 1 + \cos2x - i\sin 2x$$

I am unsure how to simplify this, as the numerator poses a problem as I try to multiply this equation by $\operatorname{cis}(2x)$ to get a real denominator.

Comment: You can say $\frac{a+ib}{c-id} = \frac{(a+ib)(c+id)}{(c-id)(c+id)} =  \frac{ac-bd }{c^2+d^2}+ i\frac{ad+bd}{c^2+d^2}$ 

and here $a=1-\cos 2x$, $b=\sin 2x$, $c=1+\cos2x$, $d=\sin 2x$. 

It looks to me as if the numerators simplify nicely

Comment: I’m one of the people who leaves $\rm e\ i\ π$ upright, just like the other universal numbers like $1\ 2\ 3$, but I left it as $i$ like a variable since that’s what everyone else here has done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that

- $\cos t = \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2}$
- $\sin t = \frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$

Comment: Thank you for allowing me to work it out myself! You are a legend!

Comment: @DonkeyKong You are welcome! That's the best way to learn. Bye

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc Yes of course! Thanks to have pointed the typos out!

Answer (score 4):

$$F=\frac{1-\cos 2x +i \sin 2x}{1+\cos 2x-i\sin 2x} = \frac{2 \sin ^2 x+ 2i \sin x \cos x}{2 \cos^2 x-2 i \sin x \cos x} =i \tan x \frac{\cos x -i \sin x}{\cos x -i \sin x}= i \tan x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

$$\dfrac{1-e^{-2ix}}{1+e^{2ix}}=\dfrac{e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}}\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{?}=e^{2ix}\cdot\dfrac{2i\sin x}{2\cos x}=?$$

Comment: Surely that would not simplify the denominator?

Comment: @Donkey, I have left the calculation of the denominator for you

Comment: Multiplying the denominator by e^(ix) will give you e^(ix) + e^(3ix) won't it? How will that help?

Comment: @Donkey, Please find the updated post