# evaluate using Euler's formula

Tags: complex-numbers

what would the value of 2$^i$ be if simplified using Euler's formula. It seems very trivial, but I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

For real $a>0,$

$$a=e^{\ln a}$$

Use [Intuition behind euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37560/intuition-behind-eulers-formula)

Answer (score 0):

Write
$$2^i=e^{i \log(2)}=\cos (\log (2))+i \sin (\log (2))$$