# How do complex number exponents actually work?

Tags: complex-numbers

**I know Euler's formula and how to take complex exponents, but in it it's $e$ to an imaginary angle, not a number, it seems.** From my understanding pi itself is not an angle, but *$\pi$ radians* is. And since cosine can only take in an angle, or at least a representation of one, and the variable is the same everywhere in Euler's formula, the exponent should be an angle and not a number. The question is then raised could I then say $e^{180i}=-1$? Surely this has a single numerical value though, right?

I've been bothered by this for a long time. Am I wrong or how can I take an exponent with a complex **number**?

Edit for the duplicate: I understand how to take them and how they're supposed work and be justifyed/proved, but raising something to the power of an angle which is what I thought was meant to be happening made me question how they *actually* worked that could allow this.

Comment: What difference do you see between an "angle" and a "number"?

Comment: @Matteo numbers represent angles so you *can* call them the same... but $\frac{\pi}{4}$, 45, and 50 can all be called the same. How I'm seeing it, like vectors, we can only talk about certain amounts of basis, but not the basis itself. You can represent a dozen of eggs using the number 1, but also using the number 12, for 12 eggs. Like the dozen of actual eggs themselves, an angle is purely geometric and can't be described as strictly *equal* to a single number. When we talk about the angle as a number, we really mean the angle is that number amount of "insert arbitrary basis angle here".

Comment: Let's put it this way: "cosine can only take in an angle", you say. Does this mean to you what. Cannot you put any number as argument of the cosine function?

Comment: I would reason this way (in the first quadrant, then you can work on the others by symmetries). Take a circle of radius one with center in the origin of the axes, then draw a half-line that intersects the circle in the first quadrant. Let $x$ be the length of the arc measured from the point $(1,0)$ (with same unit of measure used for the axes of course). Then the absissa of the intersection point is called $\cos (x)$. Does it work? No *angles* here. Only arc lengths.

Comment: Something that will help you understand this is that **there is no difference between "pi" and "pi radians" because radians are not actually a unit**. Imagine a perfect slice removed from a perfectly circular pie. The straight edge of the slice is the radius of the pie, let's say, 13cm.  The curved edge of the slice is a circular arc. Let's suppose it is exactly 14cm in your slice.  The ratio of 14cm/13cm is 14/13 -- the units cancel.  And that is how many radians the angle formed by your slice of pie at the center of the pie is.

Comment: If your slice is a quarter of the pie, and the pie radius is 13cm, then the arc will be 13pi/2 cm, and the ratio (13pi / 2) cm  / 13cm is pi/2.  NO UNITS. We only call this ratio "radians" as a convenience; radians actually have no units at all. **Radians are just unitless numbers like any other number**.  They are useful for measuring angles because the ratio of the length of the radius to the arc is invariant under any scale; if you make the radius twice as big, and you make the arc twice as big too,  the angle doesn't change, and obviously the ratio doesn't either.

Comment: So, *do not think of the angle in the exponent as being an angle at all*. Think of it as being the ratio of the arc length to the radius length, and it will all make sense.

Comment: I don't think this should be regarded as a duplicate question. The post maybe is not very well summarized in the title and that creates some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of people are giving fairly complex answers (no pun intended) about exponentiation, but I want to address a much simpler misunderstanding in your answer, which should hopefully clear up some of the issues.

> And since cosine can only take in an angle

No, the trig functions definitely take *numbers*. They're *related* to the circle, in that they're cyclic, and the "width" of their repetition is exactly  2π, which happens to be the circumference of a circle when you measure it in radians. But the argument to trig functions aren't angles except by convention.

> The question is then raised could I then say e<sup>180i</sup>=−1?

180 isn't equal to π, any more than it's equal to 50 just because 180 degrees is 50% of circle. 180 *degrees* is equal to π *radians*, but since the exponentiation operator also takes numbers, not angles, that equivalence between angle units isn't relevant.

Comment: So radians, degrees, etc are scalars with radian=1. Saying trig functions are functions of geometric angles is not always true but it can be if the number input is a function of an angle. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn, I would even go further then that. After all, even, say, curves in $\mathbb R^2$ are just metaphores (isomorphisms) based on the idea of associating couples of numbers that satisfy certain equations with coordinates of points in the $xy$-plane. Identifying things that are just connected by an isomorphism can be useful at times, but at others misleading. That is why I think the basic algebraic relation between numbers should always be clarified.

Comment: @Matteo I'm just beggining category theory and isomorphisms and stuff and have made that relation with graphs and totally agree... I see my mistake now. So is a radian equal to 1 or isomorphic to 1?

Comment: @Matteo Isomorphic because they satisfy the same universal property? Although many (infinite) numbers are associated are associated with a single angle so you'd need fibers, or something?

Comment: @BenjaminThoburn I was using the word *isomorphism* in a very loose sense. The idea of a mapping between complex structures that preserves some properties. You like to think of the argument of $\cos(\cdot )$ as if it were the measure of an angle, but you can even think of ratios between hypotenuse and side of a right-angled triangle, at least on a subset of the domain, or as the abscissa giving a certain arc lengh on a semicircle (as you saw in my answer). What is the most comfortable metaphore when you want to extend your reasoning to complex numbers?

Answer (score 5):

This is more an answer to the title of your question. A possible (and perhaps the standard) way of properly defining things is as follows. See any reasonable rigorous textbook on analysis for the proofs.

First define the exponential function $\exp : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$,  by the absolutely convergent series $\exp(z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{z^n}{n!}}$. It is easy to prove that $\exp$, restricted to the real line, takes real values. A bit more work shows that $\exp$, restricted to the real line, is strictly incresing and everywhere $>0$ and that $\exp(\mathbb{R}) = (0, \infty)$. It follows that there is a bijetive function $\log{}:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the inverse of $x \mapsto \exp(x)$ from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0, \infty)$.  The number $e$ is defined as $e: = \exp(1)$. For any positive real number $a$ and any complex number $z$, one defines $a^z$ by $a^z := \exp(\log(a) z)$. Hence, by definition, $e^z = \exp(z)$ (because $\log{(e)}=1$, by definition) and this makes sense for all complex numbers $z$.

One defines the functions $\cos, \sin : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\cos(x) := \frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+ e^{-ix})$ and $\sin(x) := \frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}- e^{-ix})$. It is a (rather non-trivial) Theorem that there is a unique smallest, strictly positive zero $p$ of the function $\cos$, restricted to the real line. One defines the number $\pi$ by $ \pi := 2p$. It can be shown that the number $\pi$ and the functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ have the "familiar properties". Notice that the identity $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ follows directly from the definitions. As does $e^{i \pi} = -1$. It always strikes me that people find these two identities so amazing.

Comment: This took the weirdness out of complex exponents as numbers and not angles. But how it comes to Euler's formula still mystified me, so I marked Xanthirs answer as accepted. Thanks, +1!

Answer (score 3):

There can be a bunch of definition of number $e$. Let's stick with this definition:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} e^t = e^t.
$$

So we want to find what number can be $z(t)=e^{it} =x(t)+iy(t)$:
$$
z'(t)=x'(t) + iy'(t)=ie^{it} = ix(t) - y(t),\\
x'(t) = -y(t),\qquad y'(t)=x(t),\\
x''(t) = -y'(t)=-x(t)
$$

Finally, $x''(t)+x(t)=0$ and $x(0)=1$, $x'(0)=-y(0)=0$ (since $e^{0i}=e^0=1$), thus $x(t)=\cos t$ as the only function that suffice the equation. Then $y=x'(t)=\sin t$.

So, we have found what number is $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$

Comment: I think the OP requires I precise definition of $\cos (\cdot )$, before, maybe geometrically based?

Comment: One technical point. If the function $\cos t$ is given in degrees (i.e. $t\in[0,360]$) then it doesn't satisfy the differential equation. The derivative of $\cos$ in degrees is $\frac{180}{\pi}$ times the derivative of the usual $\cos$.

Comment: @Matteo that's true. This is my go-to proof for explaining Euler's formula to people but it didn't help much, although it is quite elegant.

Answer (score 2):

**Angular Units and Trigonometric Functions**

When we talk about arguments to trigonometric functions, there are at least $2$ common angular units: [degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)) ($360$ to a full rotation) and [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) ($2\pi$ to a full rotation). A number of calculators also support [gradians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) ($400$ to a full rotation), which are only used in some countries and usually only in certain occupations (e.g. surveying, mining, geology).

In mathematics, we usually use radians because when angles are measured in radians, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=1\tag1
$$
That is, for small angles, $\sin(x)\sim\tan(x)\sim x$. The actual ordering for $|x|\lt\frac\pi2$ is
$$
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\le1\le\frac{\tan(x)}{x}\tag2
$$
Furthermore, when $x$ is in radians, we have the nice series
$$
\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag3
$$
and the value of
$$
\arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\tag4
$$
is in radians.

Radians are also natural because an arc which subtends $x$ radians on a circle of radius $r$ has length $rx$.

So when we talk about angles, and don't mention the units, we assume radians.

---

**The Exponential of Imaginary Numbers**

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we can write
$$
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\tag5
$$
so it seems reasonable to write
$$
e^{ix}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{ix}n\right)^n\tag6
$$
Multiplication by $1+\frac{ix}n$ increases the absolute value so minimally, that even when repeated $n$ times, it is insignificant as $n\to\infty$. However, multiplication by $1+\frac{ix}n$ rotates a number on the unit circle by a distance of $\frac xn$ counter-clockwise along the circle. When this is repeated $n$ times, it rotates a number on the unit circle by a distance of $x$.

Thus, $e^{ix}$ is a point on the unit circle whose counter-clockwise distance from $1+0i$ is $x$. This is why we use radians when saying
$$
e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)\tag7
$$
To see a more detailed explanation of $(7)$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/291754).

Answer (score 2):

In calculus, the trigonometric functions are not dealing with angles but with real numbers. Implicitly, the numbers are taken to be radians, so that $\cos\pi=-1,\sin\pi=0,$ which is compatible with Eulers' famous formula

$$e^{i\pi}=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi=-1.$$

These function are "natural", in the sense that they resemble their derivatives:

$$(e^{i\pi})'=ie^{i\pi}=(\cos x+i\sin x)'=i(\cos x+i\sin x).$$

---

You can very well define functions assuming arguments in degrees and write for instance $\cos_d180=-1,\sin_d180=0$. But these functions are a kind of "historical mistake" and do not enjoy the above derivative property, as an extra scaling factor appears.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little note that I hope can be of some use. In order to avoid confusion when dealing with *angles* and *unit of measures* of them, one can directly define the trigonometric functions starting with the arc lenght measurement.

Consider the semicircle of equation 
$$f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}, \ \ x\in [-1,1].$$
It is relatively easy to show that the arc length between point $(y, f(y))$ and point $(1,0)$ can be computed with the (improper) integral
$$A(y) = \int_y^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx, \ \ y\in [-1, 1].$$
Here the unit of measure is clearly the same as the one used for determining abscissae and ordinates.

$A(y)$ is continuous in $[-1,1]$, differentiable in $(-1,1)$, and strictly decreasing. So it has a well defined inverse function
$$A^{-1}(x)= \cos(x)$$
with domain $[0, \pi]$, where, by *definition* $A(-1) = \pi$. The rest of the cosine function can be defined using appropriate shifts and periodicity.

Comment: That makes sense for defining these functions, I hadn't thought of that.