# Relationship between circlular $i^n$ property and that $e^i{\theta}$ traces the unit circle.

Tags: complex-numbers

That $e^{i\theta}$ traces a circle $\theta \in R$ has been well discussed [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291686/how-does-ei-x-produce-rotation-around-the-imaginary-unit-circle).

However, I was always curious with it's relation to the following property of $i$:

$i^0$ = 1

$i^1$ = i

$i^2$ = -1

$i^3$ = -i

$i^4$ = 1

These properties seem like they should be related, but I can't map them too eachother.

Comment: $i = e^{i \pi/2} \implies i^k = (e^{i \pi/2})^k=e^{i k \pi/2}$ therefore, just take $\theta=k \pi/2$ in $e^{i \theta}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $i=e^{i\pi/2}$, you see that taking powers of $i$ is equivalent to making successive rotations of $\pi/2$ around the unit circle. This gives exactly the periodic sequence of $4$ elements you describe.