# how to visulaize Euler formula

Tags: exponential-function

What is $\theta$ significance in Euler equation $$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta) +i\sin(\theta)$$

Does $\theta$ have any impact on unit circle construction?

Reference: http://www.ctralie.com/Teaching/Euler/

Comment: $\theta$ is the parameter for the curve that traces out the circle (counter-clockwise starting from $1$).

Comment: is it only used to rotate the curve?Is there no impact on magnitude.

Comment: It doesn't rotate the curve, it's the parameter *for* the curve.  $\theta$ is the angle, and $\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$ is the point it corresponds to.  It won't affect the magnitude; that's the point.

Comment: why is Euler's equation applied in Laplace transform

Comment: That's a very different question, and you should probably make that a new question with some more context, specifically where you're seeing Euler's equation being used.  There is a lot of complex analytic theory that deals with the laplace equation, so without a specific context, that question is much too broad.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670158) might also prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I hope This helps

I got this by googling

[image]

Comment: thanks for the picture.it's very illustrative.Does these three colours mean three waves?What do these colours signify?why they are three waves?

Comment: what do you mean by three waves?

Comment: okay I understood that all three are changing.But from where to where it changes.I couldn't see any X,Y, or Z values on the respective axes.

Comment: in which direction is the time axis

Comment: is this continous or discrete function of time?

Comment: is it from 0 to $\infty$

Comment: okay I understood that Euler formula can be shown in time but is it from $0$ to $\infty$

Comment: without time how could Euler's formula realized.if then which domain is Euler's formula realized.

Comment: that's right.But I just want to know which domain Euler's formula is applied.

Comment: $\theta \in \mathbb R$