# What are your favorite relations between e and pi?

Tags: soft-question, exponential-function, big-list, pi

This question is for a very cool friend of mine. See, he really is interested on how seemingly separate concepts can be connected in such nice ways. He told me that he was losing his love for mathematics due to some personal stuff in his life. (I will NOT discuss his personal life, but it has nothing to do with me).

To make him feel better about math (or love of math for that matter), I was planning on giving him a sheet of paper with quite a few relations of $e$ and $\pi$

The ones I were going to give him were:

$$e^{i\pi}=-1$$

and how $e$ and $\pi$ both occur in the distribution of primes (bounds on primes has to do with $\ln$ and the regularization of the product of primes are $4\pi^2$)

Can I have a few more examples of any relations please? I feel it could mean a lot to him. I'm sorry if this is too soft for this site, but I didn't quite know where to ask it.

Comment: I think there's an integral that evaluates to $\frac\pi e$.

Comment: The power series of $\frac1{e^x+1}$ has a radius of convergence of $\pi$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Do you mean the classic $\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{e}\ dx$?

Comment: dig in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689315/interesting-and-unexpected-applications-of-pi/689369#689369 for a few more

Comment: @pjs36 This is the mathematical equivalent of a bad pun. :P

Comment: Another connection: They both appear in the word "pie."

Comment: Of course I don't know your friend nor why he's losing interest in mathematics, but I don't see how a sheet of formulas might help. He will likely be delighted that you care enough about him to actually try to do something about this, but wouldn't a fun problem or an inspiring lecture be better?

Comment: @A.P. He would like it... Just trust me on that one. The other idea you had was pretty interesting too

Comment: Not only do they both appear in the word pie but i appears in it too,and $e^{\pi i}+1=0.$

Comment: [Two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222830) [links](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670158) explaining why such connections are there in the first place.

Comment: [They are used to prove P = NP.](http://smbc-comics.com/index.php?id=3919)

Comment: Interestingly, $\pi^x$, $\pi^e$, and $\pi^{-1}$ don't occur in any of these. $e$ works well as a base, but $\pi$ doesn't really know how to be one. EDIT: Normal distribution has $\frac1{2\pi}$. But that's the only one.

Comment: My favorite:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{5}{2} \left((x - \sqrt{x^2 - 1})^{2i} + x^4\right) - 1\right) \, dx = e^{\pi}.$$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some additional possibilities

$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac {n}{e}\right)^n$$

The normal distribution is given by

$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi}e^{(-1/2)x^2}$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x)dx=1$$

A personal favorite involving the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\ln^2x \,dx=\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Also

$$\frac{e^{3+2\gamma}}{2\pi}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2+2/n}\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^n$$

Some rather unusual ones

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^2}\cos\left(\frac 9{n\pi+\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-9}}\right) =-\frac{\pi^2}{12e^3}$$

$$\pi=72\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{n\pi}-1)}-96\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(e^{2n\pi}-1)}+24\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n(e^{4n\pi}-1)}$$

*Edit:*

$$\zeta(3)=\frac{7}{180}\pi^3-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 {k^3(e^{2\pi k}-1)}$$

An approximation for the [Feigenbaum constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants) is given by

$$\pi+\tan^{-1}\left(e^\pi\right)$$

$$\int_0^\infty \Gamma(x)\,dx=e+\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi^2+\ln^2x}\,dx$$

$$\prod_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{1/k^2}}=\left(\frac{A^{12}}{2\pi e^\gamma}\right)^{\pi^2/6}$$

where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

The denominators $q_n$ of the convergents of the continued fraction expansions of almost all real numbers satisfy

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}q_n^{1/n}=e^{\pi^2/(12\ln 2)}$$

This is known as [Lévy's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy's_constant).

Comment: extremely creative findings! Where did you find these?

Answer (score 29):

I'm a fan of [$$e^\pi-\pi=20{}$$](http://www.xkcd.com/217/)(Well... almost...)

Comment: @Justin Yes, that is where my link takes you (note that the equation is blue; try clicking on it).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the equation was a link. I'm viewing on a dark theme which got rid of the blue on the equation.

Answer (score 24):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}\operatorname d\!x=\frac\pi e$$
EDIT: Also:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\operatorname d\!x=\sqrt\pi$$

Comment: I *guess* that's more interesting than mine :)

Comment: @pjs36 I added the Gaussian integral.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a beautiful relation between $\pi$ and $e$,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}=1+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}$$

It shouldn't be hard to guess who found this. As Kevin Brown of *Mathpages* remarked, *"Is there any other mathematician whose work is instantly recognizable?"*

Comment: Ramanujan?${}{}{}$

Comment: Well the question is now in the hot network questions list, and not everyone reading it will know mathematicians work by sight...

Comment: For a proof, see Mathologer's video on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iTdNmDHfV0

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks for referring the video. You know, I never did consider if the two components of the identity had closed-forms. A quick check with _Mathematica_ showed that $$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}\operatorname{erf}\left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}\left(1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}\right)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e}{2}}$$ where the first addend is the series and the second is the cfrac. It must be nice for people like Ramanujan to have Mathematica built in one's brain. :)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I investigated further. It turns out the series can also be expressed as a _nice_ continued fraction. Kindly see this [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791520/4781). I assume Mathologer is not aware of this fact.

Answer (score 12):

I honestly just like the fact that $e + \pi$ might be rational. This is the most embarrassing unsolved problem in mathematics in my opinion. It's clearly transcendental and we have no idea how to prove that it's even irrational.

They're *so* unrelated additively that we can't prove *anything* about how unrelated they are. Uh-huh.

$e\pi$ might also be rational. But we do know they can't both be (easy proof).

Answer (score 11):

$$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} =262537412640768743.99999999999925...$$

Comment: +1 for reminding me of the [Feynman point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_point) and making me crack a smile.

Comment: I don't understand any of the maths, but I gather this one is called Ramanujan's constant and related to a bunch of deep theory.

Comment: This was observed in the 19th century by a mathematician who was a performing calculating prodigy when young.

Comment: Or better: $$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} \approx 12^3(231^2-1)^3 +743.99999999999925\dots\\  e^{\pi\sqrt{427}} \approx 12^3\big((7215 + 924\sqrt{61})^2-1\big)^3+743.999999999999999999999987\dots$$ Notice the common form.

Answer (score 5):

You may consider expressing Euler's identity as $e^{i\pi}+1 = 0$ instead of the way you have it, because 0 shows up.

Comment: I already had that, please read the question before answering

Comment: I think **you** should read the answer before commenting: the answer is suggesting an alternative to what you wrote.

Comment: @nicole Yeah, but that's really just a trick to *make* $1$ and $0$ show up.  In fact you can make $0$ show up in any equation.  For instance: $G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi G(T_{\mu\nu}+\rho_\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}) \mathbf{+0}$.  There, now I've shown that the additive identity shows up in the Einstein field equations!  What could be the physical significance?! ;)

Comment: @Bye_World: Nicole's formula is the standard way to express [Euler's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity). I don't understand the point of your criticism.

Comment: @RobArthan The reason I don't like this answer is because it is emphasizes addition and not $\pi$ or $e$. I can see your point though

Comment: @RobArthan I understand that it's standard.  My (very mild) criticism is with people who say that this identity is one that links together "the $5$ most important constants in mathematics".  $1$ and $0$ only show up *because we choose to write it that way* instead of the simpler equation $e^{i\pi}=-1$ which is profound enough on its own IMO.

Comment: @Bye_World: OK. I can see why you like $e^{i\pi} = -1$.  $1$ still shows up in there though $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Wow! I am a complete idiot! Sorry all, I misread the answer.