# Ask about beautiful properties of $e$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, education, big-list

One of students asked me about "some beautiful properties (or relation) of $e$". Then I list like below 
\begin{align}
& e \equiv \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x\\[10pt]
& e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\\[10pt]
& \frac{d}{dx} (e^x) = e^x\\[10pt]
& e^{ix} = \cos x  + i \sin x  \quad \text{(Euler)}\\[10pt]
& e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0
\end{align} After this, he asked me for more relation or properties. I said 
I'll think and answer ...

Now I want help to add some relation, properties, or visual things (like proof without words)

Please help me to add something more. Thanks in advance.

***The class was math. 1. engineering

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541939/what-are-your-favorite-relations-between-e-and-pi). Also, don't forget $\int_1^e 1/x\,dx=1$.

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}e
$$

Comment: $e^{a\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)=f(x+a)$

Comment: $\exp(\text{tr}(\log(A)))=\det(A)$

Comment: The number of [derángements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) is $!n=\left[\frac{n!}{e}\right]$ for $n\ge 1$.

Comment: $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{i x t}dt=2\pi\delta(x)$

Comment: The last one is not suitable for who dos't take engineering mathematics !

Comment: $e$ is irrational, and the proof isn't that hard!

Comment: @zhw :I saw Fourier's proof for this reason ,Is there any more proof ?

Comment: $n!=\int_0^{\infty}x^{n-1}e^{-x}$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646042

Answer (score 14):

One of my favourites is the following property of $e$.

Write down a random number between $0$ and $1$. Write down another one and add it to the previous one. If the total exceeds $1$, stop. Otherwise keep adding such random numbers until the total exceeds $1$ and stop.

The expected number of such random numbers is $e$.

Comment: +1. A high school student I tutor, asked me today "why do we need $e$"? I offered an answer on the grounds of "making our life easier while producing beautiful results". Next lesson your answer will be the first thing he hears about.

Comment: This is remarkable. Do you have a reference for the property? I carried out some numerical tests just for fun, and found that if you replace the threshold with $2$, then the expected number is $e^2-e$. But if you replace the threshold with $3$, then the expected number looks like $20/3$, which seems odd...

Comment: @Théophile...there is a very elegant proof of this result I have seen somewhere on MSE involving the volume of a simplex being $\frac{1}{n!}$. If I can find it I will post a link.

Comment: I worked out the math; it comes down to solving a straightforward differential equation. If $f(x)$ is the expected number of steps to cross the finish line $x$ units away, then that function must satisfy $f(x) = 1 + \int_x^{x+1}f(t)\ \textrm dt$. It turns out that $f(3) = e^3-2e^2+e/2 = 6.66656\ldots$, a happy coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

My favourite is about derangements.

$n$ people write their name on different envelopes and put the envelopes in a box.
If they pick a random envelope back from the box, the probability that no one picks an envelope with its name is $\approx\frac{1}{e}$.

---

A number-theoretic one: if $\{p_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ is the sequence of primes,
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n} p_k = e^{n+o(n)}.$$

Comment: I think the asymptotic approximation is rather $e^{(1+o(1))n \log n}$ (according to the Wikipedia article on primorials).

Answer (score 4):

Here  are some more   relations which might be pleasing.

> From section 1.3 of *[Mathematical Constants](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521818052)* by S.R. Finch:
>
> - A    Wallis-like  infinite   product is
>     \begin{align*}
>   e=\frac{2}{1}\cdot\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
>   \cdot\left(\frac{6\cdot 8}{5\cdot 7}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}
>   \cdot\left(\frac{10\cdot 12\cdot 14\cdot 16}{9\cdot 11\cdot 13\cdot 15}\right)^{\frac{1}{8}}\cdots
>   \end{align*}
> - From Stirling's formula we derive
>     \begin{align*}
>   e=\lim_{n\rightarrow  \infty}\frac{n}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}
>   \end{align*}
> - Another continued fraction representation is
>     \begin{align*}
>   e&=2+\frac{\left.2\right|}{\left|2\right.}
>   +\frac{\left.3\right|}{\left|3\right.}
>   +\frac{\left.4\right|}{\left|4\right.}
>   +\frac{\left.5\right|}{\left|5\right.}+\cdots\\
>   &=2+\frac{2}{2+\frac{3}{3+\frac{4}{4+\frac{5}{5+\cdots}}}}
>   \end{align*}

$$ $$

> In section *Intriguing Results* in *[Real Infinite Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857456)* by D.D. Bonar and M.J. Khoury we  find
>
> - Gem 89 (American Math Monthly 42:2 pp. 111-112)
>
> \begin{align*}
> e=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{1^2}{0!}+\frac{2^2}{1!}+\frac{3^2}{2!}+\frac{4^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Here is the (simple) continued fraction for $e-1.$ The pattern continues forever, 1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,1,1,10,1,1,12,...

To get $e$ itself add one, this is the same as changing the first $1$ to a $2$

$$  
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 4 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 &   \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{1}{1} &  &  \frac{2}{1} & &  \frac{5}{3}  & & \frac{7}{4} & &  \frac{12}{7} & &   \frac{55}{32}  & &   \frac{67}{39}  & &   \frac{122}{71}   & &   \frac{799}{465}  \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Let's say that a number is cut into equal parts and then multiply those parts together, for example take number $20$ and divide it by $4$ ($20/4=5$), as result we have:

$5\times5\times5\times5=625$

The question here is to find the number $n\in \mathrm{N}$ such that is maximizes

$r = \arg \max_{n,m} \prod_{i=1}^{n}m$

where

$m=(\mathrm{your\:choice\:of\:number})/n$

We can show that the number $r$ is maximized when $m\approx e$. In the case of choosing $20$ we have

$20/7\approx e$

so

$r=(2.8)^7$