# Proof of this formula for $\sqrt{e\pi/2}$ and similar formulas.

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, pi, continued-fractions

\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{e\pi}{2}}=1+\frac{1}{1\cdot3}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{1}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots+\cfrac1{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{2}{1+\cfrac{3}{1+\ddots}}}}
\end{align}

as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1542090/356647).

Is there other series that relate $\pi$ and $e$?

Also, it's possible to rewrite the continued fraction above in terms of known functions/numbers?

Answer (score 4):

The infinite sum is
 $\,\sqrt{e \pi/2}\,\textrm{erf}(\sqrt{1/2})\,$
as given in [OEIS sequence A060196](https://oeis.org/A060196). The
continued fraction is $\,\sqrt{e \pi/2}\,\textrm{erfc}(\sqrt{1/2})\,$
as given in [OIES sequence A108088](https://oeis.org/A108088). The sum, of course, is $\,\sqrt{e \pi/2}\,$ since
 $\,\textrm{erf}(x) + \textrm{erfc}(x) = 1\,$ by definition.

Comment: The first addend (the series) can also be expressed as a _nice_ continued fraction. Kindly see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4791520/4781).

Comment: And apparently, there's a _cubic_ version of the identity as discussed in this [new post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4792229/4781).

Answer (score 2):

About 2 years ago I discovered a lot of pretty nice series that relate $\pi$ and $e$, for instance :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{16n^4-1}=\frac{\pi}{32}\cdot\frac{e^{\pi}+1}{e^{\pi}-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{4n^4+1}=\frac{\pi}{8}\cdot\frac{e^{\pi}-1}{e^{\pi}+1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(4n^4+1)(16n^4-1)}=\frac{\pi}{10}\cdot\frac{e^{\pi}}{e^{2\pi}-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2(32n^4+3)}{(4n^4+1)(16n^4-1)}=\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot\frac{e^{2\pi}+1}{e^{2\pi}-1}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2(64n^4+11)}{(4n^4+1)(16n^4-1)}=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{e^{3\pi}-1}{(e^{2\pi}-1)(e^{\pi}-1)}$$

If you're looking for any mathematical identity that relates $\pi$ and $e$, I can also suggest :

$\cdot$ The Stirling limit : $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

$\cdot$ The well known integral : $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1}\text{d}x=\frac{\pi}{e}$$

$\cdot$ Victor Adamchik's integrals : $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{(e^x-x+1)^2+\pi^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$ $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{(e^x-x)^2+\pi^2}=\frac{1}{1+\Omega}$$
Where $\Omega$ is the mathematical constant defined by $\text{ }\Omega e^{\Omega}=1$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where can I read more about these series and other similar ones? Is there any paper or a link?

Comment: Actually when I say "I discovered them", I mean that I'm the one who derived them.
So as far as I'm aware, there are no papers about them. That being said, Mathematica can handle all of them.

Comment: @Pinteco: the first five identities are consequences of the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), if you are interested.