# Prove $e^{i \pi} = -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove Euler's formula: $\exp(i t)=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-expi-t-costi-sint)

I recently heard that $e^{i \pi} = -1$.

WolframAlpha confirmed this for me, however, I don't see how this works.

Comment: Do you know the imaginary unit $i$? Do you know how complex exponentiation is defined?

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula ?

Comment: To answer your (now deleted) question on how to put an equation into LaTeX, you can click on edit (below your question) to see what I did. Some links and references on that can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

Comment: @Theo Buehler, thanks for that. I was trying to use parenthesis instead of braces. I'll remember that next time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This identity follows from Euler's Theorem, 
\begin{align}
e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta,
\end{align}
which has many proofs. The one that I like the most is the following (sketched). Define $f(\theta) = e^{-i \theta}(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$. Use the quotient rule to show that $f^{\prime}(\theta)= 0$, so $f(\theta)$ is constant in $\theta$. Evaluate $f(0)$ to prove that $f(\theta) = f(0)$ everywhere.

Take $\theta = \pi$ for your claim.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the Wikipedia page

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity#Derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity#Derivation)