# Must Have Theorems, Identies, etc... in Your Mathematical Arsenal

Tags: big-list

Lately I have been getting into solving problems in some of the math journals I enjoy reading.  More and more I find that solvers employ a theorem or identity that makes solving the problem much easier. Sometimes, that identity or theorem is one I am not familiar with.

For instance a few weeks ago I saw the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem used on a problem in the Fibonacci Quarterly.  It was used in a very slick way, and was a theorem that up to that point I was unfamiliar with.

My question is: what are some of the best theorems, identities, inequalities, etc.. that the consummate problem solver should have at their disposal?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a similar question on the site asking for such a list. Have you tried searching?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178940/proofs-that-every-mathematician-should-know/

Comment: Tychonoff's theorem, Cauchy's integral formula (and its related results), Zorn's lemma, Banach-Alaoglu theorem, Riesz representation theorem and contraction mapping principle are some big ones that have been really useful for me.

Comment: "(big-list) Please do not use this as the only tag for a question."

Comment: I did a very quick search, and @Thomas: I wasn't sure what other tags I should use.  I tried "identities" or "thoerems" but neither of those existed.  But I will put those in.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Tychonoff's Theorem and Zorn's Lemma are the same thing!  And I think Banach-Alaoglu is just about equivalent to those. To the OP I would also add other common independent axioms of ZF: CH, $\neg$CH, MA, etc.

Comment: @TomCruise Most definitely. The particular interpretations are important I suppose since they get used all over.

Comment: *Must Have Theorems, Identies, etc.* - **From what domain?**

Comment: @Lucian well from analysis, number theory, combinatorics, etc... anything from the big areas of study that would be most useful in solving problems.

Comment: The answer for each of this individual subdomains is in itself a big list, or even an entire manual.

Comment: Big list should surely not be the only tag here - this is too broad for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is newbies list,a staret pack of a kind:

-Mean value theorem

-Chain,addition,multiplication and other such rules for limits and derivatives

-Cauchy mean value theorem

-Rolles theorem

-Recursion theorem

-Variations of axiom of choice

-Darboux theorem

-Fundamental theorem of arithmetic

-Division algorithm

-Pigeonhole principle

-Binomial theorem

Comment: I think Cauchy's, Rolle's and some other you didn't mentioned like Heine-Cantor could be packed in a "fundamental theorem on continuity" thing

Comment: It is because I did not know that good sir... :D