# Why Euler's formula is true?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove Euler’s formula: $\exp(i t)=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-expi-t-costi-sint)

I need to know why Euler's formula is true? I mean why is the following true:
$$
e^{ix}  = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)
$$

Comment: Wrong name, wrong formula.

Comment: You can try plugging $i \theta$ into the Taylor series for $e^x$, and watch as the Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\cos$ appear, as if by magic.  I imagine it was quite a shock to Euler when he did this.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx} e^{ix}=ie^{ix}\\ \frac{d}{dx} \cos{x}+i\sin{x}=i(\cos{x}+i\sin{x})$

Comment: See: http://pundit.pratt.duke.edu/wiki/Complex_Numbers and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Notice $$\sin (x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + ..... $$ and $$i\cos (x) = i - i\frac{x^2}{2!} + i\frac{x^4}{4!} - i\frac{x^6}{6!} + .... $$ Now add them and use the fact that $i^2 = -1$, $i^3 = -i$, $i^4 = 1$. You should obtain $e^{ix}$. Also notice: $$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ....... $$