# How does $e^{\pi i}$ equal $-1$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I was on [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com/179/) a while back and there was the equation $e^{\pi i}$ which somehow miraculously equals $-1$. So, I put it [into Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=e%5E(pi*i)) and it works. So, I tried solving it on my own:

$\begin{align}
e^{\pi i} &= -1 \\
\ln e^{\pi i} &= \ln (-1) \\
\pi i \times \ln e &= \ln (-1) \\
\pi i \times 1 &= \ln (-1) \\
\pi i &= \ln (-1)
\end{align}$

But that's as far as I can get as $\ln (-1)$ gives `Error` on my calculator. So how does $e^{\pi i} = -1$ work?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html

Comment: $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

Comment: Also check http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalBranch.html

Comment: @copper.hat but why?

Comment: Depends on  your starting point. If $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$, then plugging in the value $i \theta$ and collecting real and imaginary parts will result in the above formula.

Comment: I don't know what Algebra II means (as in what level). To give an answer that is useful to you I need to know how you define $\ln$, $x \mapsto e^x$, $\cos$ and $\sin$ in the first place.

Comment: An intuitive picture is painted by considering polygonal approximations to exponential spirals in the complex plane as they approach the unit circle in view of the formula $e^{i\pi}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{i\pi}{n}\right)^n$. Depicted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ExpIPi.gif) on Wikipedia.

Comment: I love how the OP said, "I put it into the calculator and it works". Love this, my favorite example of how non-intuitive math can be.

Comment: @ColeJohnson, $e^{i\pi}=-1$ is a consequence of how the objects $e$, $\pi$ and raising a number to the power of a complex number are defined. There is no deep truth behind the equation as some like to think. You are confused because you have a feeling for what $e$, $\pi$ and $-1$ are but you can't see the relation. The mystery lies in the definition of $i$ and what it means to have it in the exponent. It just turns out that with the definitions we have of those elements one ends up with the $e^{i\pi}=-1$ equation.

Comment: You can think of $e^{i\theta}$ as a rotation on complex plane. a rotation of $\pi$ will take you from 1 to -1.

Comment: Related to this previous question: [How to prove Euler's formula: $\exp(it)=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3510/856)

Comment: @copper.hat basically trigonometry and everything below

Comment: @PrinceAli Well, before I attempt to solve something that I havn't had much experience in, I put it into a calculator so I know what I'm trying to reach

Comment: Cole, I do not have a satisfactory simple answer. I think the quickest is to define $\exp,\sin, \cos$ via Taylor series.
Let $\phi(t) =e^{it}$, and show that there is a smallest $s>0$ such that $\phi(s) = i$ and let $\pi = 2s$. We can also show that $\phi(s)\phi(t) = \phi(s+t)$ from which the result will follow.
(Also, $\phi$ traverses the entire circle, $|\dot{\phi}(t)|=1$ and the length of $\phi$ (on $[0,2 \pi]$) is $2 \pi$, and $\cos, \sin$ have the usual trigonometric interpretations.) However, this involves a familiarity with analysis that I would guess is not consistent with Algebra II.

Comment: @copper.hat actually, that is what we are taught in Alg2/Trig at my school.

Comment: Excellent! Hopefully my comment will help then...

Comment: What happened to your iPhone?

Comment: @беркай I think it tried dividing by zero :(

Comment: @ColeJohnson as I answered below what matters is how the domain of $\log$ is defined. This answer returned me as a negative reputation but this is the situation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an interesting proof that you may have seen.

Let us define

$$e^x := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Then
\begin{align}e^{i \pi} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(i\pi)^n}{n!} \\
&= 1+i\pi-\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\frac{\pi^3}{3!} + \cdots\\
&= \left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{2}+\frac{\pi^4}{4!}+\cdots\right) + i\left(\pi-\frac{\pi^3}{3!}+\frac{\pi^5}{5!}+\cdots\right) \\ \\
&= \cos \pi +i\sin \pi \\ \\
&= -1\end{align}

This method can be generalized to show Euler's identity, $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin\theta$.  From this we find that $e^z$ is actually a periodic function over $2\pi i$, and because of this, it follows that $\log z$, as the inverse of $e^z$, must be multivalued (because, $e^{i\theta} = e^{i\theta +2\pi i}=e^{i\theta -2\pi i}=\cdots = e^{i\theta+2 \pi i n}$ where $n \in \mathbb Z$).

Comment: According to Sarason, "Complex Function Theory," Page 35, the generalization mentioned is how Euler himself came up with his expression.

Comment: I feel it should be noted that @AmWhy left your answer as a remark at the end of her post.

Comment: @Argon: I aligned your equations using the align setting.

Answer (score 17):

$e^{\pi i}$ corresponds to $z = (-1, 0) = -1$ on the unit circle in the complex plane.

That is, it is positioned $\pi = 180^\circ$ from the position (1, 0) on the complex unit circle. It has no "height" in the direction of either $i$ or $-i$.

[image: unit circle on complex plane]

From $e^{\pi i} = -1$, we obtain [***Euler's Identity***](http://www.answers.com/topic/euler-s-identity): $e^{\pi i} + 1 = 0$.

---

Indeed one of the amazing things is that $e$ and $\pi$ have *a lot* to do with each other:

> For example, see [**Euler's formula**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html): $\quad e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.

So $e^{\pi i} = \cos {\pi} + i \sin {\pi} = -1 + (i \times 0)$.

A visual image may help make sense of Euler's formula and $e^{\pi i}$:

[image: unit circle and Euler's formula]

---

*If you really want to pursue this question, and how Euler came up with his formula, you may want take on the following **challenge**:*

Try computing the Taylor expansion ([Maclaurin Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)) of $e^{\pi i}$ and see that it equals sum of the Taylor (Maclaurin) expansions of $\cos {\pi}$ and $i \sin {\pi}$. Both sum to $-1$! Or if you are lazy, you can look over at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#Complex_numbers)

BOTH $e$ and $i$ are fascinating, because they "crop up" almost everywhere in math, physics, and many other fields. For more ways of representing $e$, look at [this list](http://www.answers.com/topic/list-of-representations-of-e).

Comment: That I get, but my question is why? $\pi$ and $e$ have nothing to do with eachother

Comment: @ColeJohnson, clearly they do...

Comment: Euler begs to differ...

Comment: @ColeJohnson: I wonder what you mean by '$\pi$ and $e$ have nothing to do with each other'. If you've done a course in analysis you'll know that the exponential function is very closely related to trig functions (via complex numbers). The former is related to $e$ and the latter are related to $\pi$.

Comment: I love dynamical plots Amy. +)

Answer (score 7):

First you need to understand [why](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html), for a complex number $z$, $z = x + iy$ and $z = r e^{i \theta}$ -- where $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$ -- are equivalent. From that, $e^{\pi i\left(1+2n\right)} = -1$ and $\ln \left(-1\right) = \pi i \left(1 + 2 n\right)$ follow for $n$ integer.

To see the former, substitute $r=1$ and $\theta = \pi\left(1+2n\right)$ into $r e^{i \theta} = r \cos \theta + i r \sin \theta$.

To see the latter, take $\ln$ of the result $e^{\pi i\left(1+2n\right)} = -1$, or take $\ln$ of $z = e^{i \theta}$:
$$
\ln z = \ln r e^{i \theta} = \ln r + i \theta.
$$
With $z = -1$, $r = 1$ and $\theta = \left(1+2n\right)$, and
$$
\ln \left(-1\right) = \pi i\left(1+2n\right).
$$

Answer (score 6):

$\pi$ is 180 degrees.

-1 is 180 degrees away from 1, around the complex plane's origin.

$e^{0i}$ is 1.

$e^{\theta i}$ is a point on the unity circle around the complex plane origin determined by the angle $\theta$, in radians. So if $\theta =\pi$, we get -1.

Complex exponentiation with other bases is also a rotation around the unity circle. For instance $5^{\phi i}$ also traces out a circle as we vary $\phi$. However, for such other bases, $\phi$, though an angle, isn't an angle measured in radians, and so $5^{\pi i}$ is not -1.

The correspondence between radians and the coefficient is only in the case of $e$.

$e$ is a special number which is inherently connected to the special number $\pi$ in multiple ways.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways of seeing this.

Consider the function $f(\theta)=e^{i \theta}$. Then $f''(\theta)=-f(\theta)$. Differential equations tell us that any such solution is a linear combination of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ [reason:The Wronskiansk tells us that $f, \sin(x), \cos(x)$ are linearly dependent, while $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ are linearly independent].

Thus $f(\theta)=A \cos(\theta)+ B \sin(\theta)$ for some $A,B$. Setting $\theta=0$ Yields $A=1$, and derivating and setting $\theta=0$ Yields $B=i$.

---

**Second apprroach**

Let $f(x,y)=e^x (\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$.

Then $f(z_1+z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$, and $f$ is continuous.Thus, $f$ is an exponential function. Since $f(1)=e$ we get that $f(z)=e^z$.

Note $f(z)$ satisfies the condition of CR- equations, and is $C_1$, thus it is analityc. Hence, it is the only analityc extension of $e^x$ to the complex plane.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the principal branch of $\log(z)$, we have

$$\log{(-1)}= \ln{|-1|}+ i \arg{(-1)}=i \pi.$$

Your calculator considers the domain of the $\log$ function as $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Don't forget about multivaluedness!

Comment: @Argon that's okay right now.

Comment: Does this imply that an iPhone is not a smart phone?

Comment: @Dirk It implies that it might be smart but not that much.