# Euler's identity and the number $e$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Why is the number $e$ in Euler identity formula:

$$e^{iπ} = -1$$

I don't get it, why we use as base $e$.

Comment: Here is an old answer I gave to a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233283/why-did-euler-use-e-to-represent-complex-numbers/1233325#1233325

Comment: [See this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dhHrg-KbJ0): it will give you a detailed explanation.

Comment: because if it would be the number $\tau$ then Euler would be called Tuler.

Comment: This is also relevant: [How does $e^{\pi i}$ equal $-1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/253267).

Comment: Are you aware of complex analysis?

Comment: I am just beginning with complex analysis, but I saw this formula and I got interested.