# Find the remainder of the polynomial division $p(x)/(x^2-1)$ for some $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $f(x) = x^{10}+5x^9-8x^8+7x^7-x^6-12x^5+4x^4-8x^3+12x^2-5x-5. $

Without using long division (which would be horribly nasty!), find the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $x^2-1$.

I'm not sure how to do this, as the only way I know of dividing polynomials other than long division is synthetic division, which only works with linear divisors.  I thought about doing $f(x)=g(x)(x+1)(x-1)+r(x)$, but I'm not sure how to continue.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: plug in $1$ and $-1$ to get two values of $r(x)$ which is linear.  From there you can get what $a,b$ are in $ax+b.$

Comment: Hint : Use the horner-scheme. To avoid complications, first use it for 1, then for -1. There is a compact notation, described in wikipedia.

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Answer (score 6):

Plug in $1$ and $-1$ to get two values of $r(x)$ which is linear.  From there you can get what $a,b$ are in $ax+b.$

Since
$$f(x)=g(x)(x+1)(x-1)+r(x)$$

we have

$$ f(1)=g(1)(1+1)(1-1)+r(1)=r(1)=-10$$
$$ f(-1)=g(1)(-1+1)(-1-1)+r(-1)=r(-1)=16$$

We know the remainder is of degree $1$, so

$r(x)=ax+b$

and now we know,
$$r(1)=ax+b=a+b=-10$$
$$r(-1)=ax+b=-a+b=16$$

so, solve

$$a+b=-10$$
$$-a+b=16$$

which yields, $a=-13$ $b=3$, so

$$r(x)=-13x+3$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod\ }x^{\large 2}\!-1\!:\,\ x^{\large 2}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}{x^{\large 2n}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#c00}{x^{\large 2n+1}\equiv x},\ $ hence

$  f(x) =\,  \overbrace{(c_0 + c_2\color{#0a0}{ x^2} + c_4\color{#0a0}{ x^4}+\cdots)}^{\large \color{#0a0}{f_0(x)}} \ +\  \overbrace{(c_1\color{#c00} x + c_3\color{#c00}{x^3} + c_5\color{#c00}{x^5} + \cdots)}^{\large \color{#c00}{f_1(x)}}$

$\qquad \equiv \ (c_0 \ +\  c_2\  +\  c_4\  \  + \   \cdots)\,\color{#0a0}1 +  (c_1\  +\,\  c_3\ \  +\  \ c_5 \ +\ \cdots)\,\color{#c00}x $

$\qquad \equiv\ f_0(1)\,\color{#0a0}1 + f_1(1)\, \color{#c00}x,\ $ where $\,f_0(x),\ f_1(x)\,$ are [the $\rm\color{#0a0}{even}$ and $\rm\color{#c00}{odd}$ parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3514/242) of $\,f(x).$

e.g. a familiar numerical instance when $\,x=10\,$ in radix $10$ (decimal) arithmetic

$\!\! \bmod 99\!:\ \color{#c00}5\color{#0a0}4\color{#c00}3\color{#0a0}2\color{#c00}1\color{#0a0}0\equiv 
(\color{#c00}{5\!+\!3\!+\!1}),(\color{#0a0}{4\!+\!2\!+\!0})\equiv \color{#c00}9\color{#0a0}6\equiv \color{#c00}5\color{#0a0}4+\color{#c00}3\color{#0a0}2+\color{#c00}1\color{#0a0}0\ $ by $\,10^2\equiv 1$

Comment: In other words, add up all the even-degree coeffs and you get the constant term; add up all the odd-deg coeffs and you get the linear term.

Comment: This is a rather sophisticated way doing it. I like it.