# Finding roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to find $2^{1/5} $. Using the formula, and noticing $2 = 2e^{0 i} $, we have

$$ 2^{1/5} = 2^{1/5} \bigg( \cos( \frac{ 0}{5} + \frac{ 2 \pi k}{5} ) + i \sin( \frac{ 0}{n} + \frac{ 2 \pi k}{n} ) \bigg) $$

My confusing. I notice we can also write $2 = 2e^{2 \pi k} = 2e^{4 \pi k} = .... $ Do I need to consider every case, or would it be enough to just consider the case when $2 = 2e^{0i } $ as above?

Comment: $2 \neq 2e^{2\pi k}$ but $2 = 2e^{2k\pi i}$

Comment: Is the question to find explicit complex representations, say in the form $a + bi$ for $a, b \in \Bbb R$, of each of the five $5$th roots of $2$?

Comment: Take a circle of radius $2$ on the Argand Plane . Now divide $2\pi$ into $5$ parts and find each compLex number, taking the argument of each 5 parts with the x-axis.

Comment: I dont think you can get rid of $2^{\frac15}$ for the complex roots.http://www4a.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP6031g7f94ii5e3c672900001cf53h02dgdge9ac?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=19&w=240.&h=211.&cdf=Coordinates&cdf=Tooltips

Answer (score 1):

One way to attack this baby is to remember that  the number of $n$-th complex roots of a number is always $n$, *and* that those $n$ roots form the vertices of an $n$-sided regular polygon on the Complex plane. So there are $3$ cube roots, forming a triangle, $4$ cube roots, forming a square, $5$ fifth roots, forming a pentagon, and so forth.

[image]

Int the above diagram, the pentagon is superimposed on the Complex plane. It has been broken broken up into five segments. The angle between each segment is $1/5$ that of a full circle. That is, each angle is $2\pi/5$. Each of the points, $A$ to $E$ is located by two numbers: One number is the distance from the centre of the figure. The other number is the angle that around the circle that it's located away from point $A$.

The angles are marked on the diagram. $A$ is $0$, (but it's marked on the diagram as $10\pi/5=2\pi$ because travelling $2\pi$ radians from any point on a circle will take you back to where you started).

Your angles are as follows:

$A. 0$
$B. 4\pi/5$
$C. 2\pi/5$
$D. 6\pi/5$
$E. 8\pi/5$

The number you also want to know the *argument* which is the Real number value of the length of each of those spikes from the centre to a point. That number is the Real value of $2^{1/5}$.

How do you arrange all this information is your final stretch. If we designate $z$ as your Complex root, $r$ as your *argument* (which is $2^{1/5}$ in each case) and $\theta$ for your angles, your general forms are:

$$z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$$  and  $$z = e^{i\theta}$$

(Why these are equivalent is [another story](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1423172/266049).)

So, your five roots are:

$$A.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{0i}=2^{\frac{1}{5}}$$
$$B.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{2\pi i/5}$$
$$C.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{4\pi i/5}$$
$$D.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{6\pi i/5}$$
$$E.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{8\pi i/5}$$

Alternatively, these can be expressed as:

$$A.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}(\cos 0 + i\sin 0)= 2^{\frac{1}{5}}$$
$$B.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}(\cos \frac{2\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{2\pi}{5})$$
$$C.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}(\cos \frac{4\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{4\pi}{5})$$
$$D.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}(\cos \frac{6\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{6\pi}{5})$$
$$E.\; 2^{\frac{1}{5}}(\cos \frac{8\pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{8\pi}{5})$$

These are your five roots, each expressed in two forms. The first form is  *polar* and the second is *rectangular*.

Any of these numbers, multiplied by itself five times will yield $2$. Multiplying a rectangular form by itself five times is tedious. Multiplying a polar form is amazingly simple. I'll end off with one example.

$$[2^{\frac{1}{5}}e^{4\pi i/5}]^5=[2^{1/5}]^5[e^{4\pi i/5}]^5=
2e^{20\pi i/5}=2e^{4\pi i}$$

Since $4\pi$ is two full rotations about the circle, $e^{4\pi i}=e^{0 i}=1$
So the equation above finishes:

$$2e^{4\pi i}= 2(1) = 2$$

which is what we wanted to show.

EDIT:
To address the OP directly, you can always add $2\pi$ to any angle without changing the value of $z$ just as you can go around a circle exactly once and end up where you started.

So, you need only show the solution for $\theta=0$ and $\theta=2\pi$ takes care of itself.

Comment: @user135395 I've added a statement to directly address the question at the end of your OP

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Put $2=x^5$;$x^5=1.2$ Now take 5th roots of both sides. And then use all $5$ 5th roots of unity.

Comment: Explain the downvotes.