# about Euler's $e^{iπ}=−1$

Tags: plane-curves

since $e^π= 23.14...$   and this to the power of $i = -1$ ,
would $23.05...$ equal $-.9995$ ?
would $23.27...$ equal $-1.003$ ?
in other words, does every positive real number generate a different value when raised to the $i$ power or are *all* $n^i$ equal to $-1$?

I've seen several videos about the Euler identity but but no one addresses the obvious non-mathematician's question. If there is a unique point on a curve in the complex plane that is $-1$ ... and that point corresponds to $e^π$ ... then this is an important fact. If *every* number generates that same $-1$, then Euler's identity appears trivial.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Bantokfomoki related with your question (I guess), here you have a more generic visualization of the pattern you are talking about: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436167/is-this-a-valid-visualization-of-eulers-identity-as-a-more-generic-pattern

Answer (score 5):

Complex exponentials with positive real bases have a very simple and unambiguous definition:
$$
x^z = e^{z\cdot \ln x}
$$
That means that if you change the value of $x$ slightly, you do change the value of the resulting exponent slightly as well. However, it doesn't go the way you think: Any (positive, real) number raised to a purely imaginary number has absolute value $1$ (because by the deifnition above, it corresponds to $e$ raised to some other purely imaginary number). What changes is its argument (i.e. angle in the complex plane). So, for instance,
$$
23.05^i \approx -0.999992 + 0.004i
$$
is above $-1$ along the unit circle, while
$$
23.27^i \approx -0.99998 -0.0056i
$$
is below.