# Eigenvalues for correlation matrix which have the form of an harmonic function

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, harmonic-analysis, signal-processing

As a continuation to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607969/how-come-ce-frac-phi-i-phi-j-rho-has-the-form-of-e-in-phi-i-and), I took the matrix $C_{2 \times 2}$ which is:
$$C=\left[
    \begin{array}{}
      a& ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{2}}\\
      ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{2}} & a    
    \end{array}
\right] $$

And I found it's eigen vector and eigenvalues which are:

$$v_1 = \left[
    \begin{array}{}
      1 \\
      1    
    \end{array}
\right]
,v_2 = \left[
    \begin{array}{}
      -1 \\
      1    
    \end{array}
\right] \\ \lambda_1 = a+ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{\rho}},\lambda_2 = a-ace^{-\frac{|\phi_1-\phi_2|}{\rho}} 
 $$

So, it is still not clear to me why the author sais that the eigenvectors has the form $e^{in\phi_i}$. I mean, this form doesn't even have a form of a vector... and I specifically found the eigenvectors, and there isn't any complex component in it. Clearly I am missing something very crucial and basic here..

any help?
Thanks!

[image]