# If $e^{i\pi}=-1$, then what does $e^{2i\pi}$ equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

As the question says. As according to Euler's formula, $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ thus $e^{i\pi}=-1$, what therefore does $e^{2i\pi} $ equal?

Comment: $$e^{2\pi i}=(e^{i\pi})^2$$

Comment: $e^{i\theta}=cos\theta+isin\theta$ and the angle is.....$-2\pi$, so...

Comment: 1 is what I believe.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: would that work with $e^{2\pi i}=(e^{i2})^\pi$ ?

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws

Comment: @labbhattacharjee This page is only about $a^b$ for real $a,b$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents

Comment: @labbhattacharjee You probably mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers since your second link is also about $a^b$ with real (and even positive) $a$. When $a$ is negative or complex, it's much more difficult to define $a^b$ consistently, but you already knew that I guess.

Comment: Why has @almagest edited my question and post. It should be e^(2*i*pi) NOT e^-(2*i*pi)

Comment: The original title did mention `e^-2ipi`, with a minus sign.

Comment: Not really complex analysis. More like algebra / precalculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It equals $(-1)^2 = 1$.

More generally, for a real number $\theta$, we might say that $e^{i \theta}$ is equal to the coordinates of the point on the unit circle at angle $\theta$ with the right horizontal axis, where the coordinates are given as complex numbers. This is sometimes written
$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta.$$

This might feel funny, but this can be made formal. See for instance [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3510/9754).

The coordinates of the point at angle $\pi$ are $-1$, and the coordinates of the point at angle $2\pi$ are $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that: $e^{-2\pi i}$ is equal to $(e^{i\pi})^{-2}$; then

$$\frac{1}{e^{2i\pi}}=1$$