# The expression $\frac{(\text{cis}\ 75^\circ)(\text{cis}\ 80^\circ−1)}{\text{cis}\ 8^\circ−1}$ can be written as $r\ \text{cis}\ \theta$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\text{cis}(θ)=\cos θ+i\sin θ$.  The expression $\dfrac{(\text{cis}\ 75^\circ)(\text{cis}\ 80^\circ−1)}{\text{cis}\ 8^\circ−1}$ can be written as $r\ \text{cis}\ \theta$ where $0 \le \theta < 360^\circ$.  Find $\theta$ in degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

cis$(2y)-1=\cos2y+i\sin2y-1=-2\sin^2y+2i\sin y\cos y$

$=2i\sin y(\cos y+i\sin y)=2i\sin y\cdot $cis$(y)$

Here $2y=8^\circ,80^\circ$

We may use : [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t)

Comment: I simplified it down to $\dfrac{\text{cis} \ 75^\circ \sin 40 ^\circ \ \text{cis} \ 40^\circ}{\sin 4^\circ \ \text{cis} \ 4^\circ}$.  What should I do now?

Comment: @YunaKun, cis$(a)\cdot$cis$(b)/$cis$(c)=$cis$(a+b-c)$

Comment: That was the formula I was forgetting!  Thanks!