# Calculate the sum of the series that contain trigonometric funtion $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{2^k}\cos \frac{{k\pi }}{3}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

This is the series: $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{2^k}\cos \frac{{k\pi }}{3}} $$

Because the series contain trigonometry so that I've tried a lot but still can't solve it with common methods. Many thanks to all that can solve it for me. This question is in my seminar test at university.

Comment: hint: $\cos(kx) = \dfrac{e^{ikx}+ e^{-ikx}}{2}$

Comment: Then remove trigonometry: try to compute $\cos(k\pi/3)$ for some values of $k$, then notice a pattern.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BCos%5Bk*Pi%2F3%5D,%7Bk,0,11%7D%5D) might give you an idea !

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098275/another-way-to-express-textcis-75-circ-textcis-83-circ-textcis

Comment: The result is $\displaystyle\frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{3}}\sin\frac{(n+1)\pi}{3}$ . You've got several senseful proposals - do you see how you can get the solution ?!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

$$\cos\frac{1\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{2}\\
\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}=-\frac{1}{2}\\
\cos\frac{3\pi}{3}=-1\\
\cos\frac{4\pi}{3}=-\frac{1}{2}\\
\cos\frac{5\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{2}\\
\cos\frac{6\pi}{3}=1
$$

For $k>6$, use the fact that $\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos(x)$