# Why does Euler's formula have to be $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, proof-explanation

In part one of this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYBFTlunmxY) the uploader goes on to explain the calculus proof for Euler's Formula.

The Formula
$$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$
Differentiate
$$ie^{ix} = f'(x) + i g'(x)$$
Multiply original formula by $i$
$$ie^{ix} = if(x) - g(x)$$
Equate the differentiation and the multiplied version
$$f'(x) + ig'(x) = if(x) - g(x)$$
Equate real and imaginary (and cancel the i)
$$f'(x) = -g(x) \qquad g'(x) = f(x)$$

Then he goes on to explain $f(x) = \cos(x)$ and $g(x) = \sin(x)$. My question is why can't $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = -\cos(x)$? Can further proof be added to this proof to eliminate $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = -\cos(x)$?

Comment: Else the equality would be false at $x=0$, or you wouldn't have a holomorphic function to do complex analysis with, etc. and that all gets messy.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt It is related but not the same as I already have a proof but want some to explain the end result of it

Comment: Yes, of course.  Hence I did not have it as possible duplicate :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because we know the initial condition $e^{i0}=1$ holds. As with most differential equations, there's an family of answers that you need to use the initial condition to find the correct one for.

Comment: Stella (+1) for the answer.  I reject the so-called proof of Euler's formula inasmuch as it uses a result from real analysis (i.e., $\frac{de^x}{dx}=e^x$) and presumes that it holds for the yet-to-be-defined object $e^{ix}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Agreed. My preferred way is to define $e^{ix}$ by the Taylor polynomial and then use complex analysis to prove that the power series preserves the usual properties of the real analysis function $e^x$. Euler's Equation is then simply obtained from comparing power series.

Comment: Yes, that's a good standard approach.

Answer (score -1):

Let z=cos(x)+isin(x)
When you 8derive it (in terms of x), 
 z'=-sin(x)+icos(x) 
And since we are in the complex world, -1=i×i
=>z'=i×isin(x)+icos(x)=i(cos(x)+isin(x))=iz
This pretty much makes it a first order differential equation.
After dividing by z and multiplying by dx (z'=dz/dx) both on both sides  and integrating both sides, you get:
ln(z)=ix+c
ln(cos(x)+isin(x))=ix+c
If we set x=0, cos(0)=1,sin(0)=0 and ln(1)=0
=> ln(1)=c=>c=0
=> ln(cos(x)+isin(x))=ix
e^ix=cos(x)+isin(x).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE. Producing beautiful and beautifully formatted text is one of the points that makes an answer good: if you want to learn how to do this, please have a look at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).