# Solving a complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$(z+i)^3+2(z+i)^{-3}+2=0$$

What I have manage to come up with is:

$$w=(z+i)^3$$

$$w+2w^{-1}+2=0$$

$$w+\frac{2}{w}+2=0$$

$$w^2+2w+2=0$$

$$w_{1,2}=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4-8}}{2}=\frac{-2\pm2i}{2}=-1\pm i$$

$$(z+i)^3=-1\pm i$$

How to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Now $-1-i=\sqrt2e^{i(\pi+\pi/4)}$

and $-1+i=\sqrt2e^{i(\pi-\pi/4)}$

Now use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers) and [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t)

Answer (score 0):

Using polar notation we have:
$$
-1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}} \qquad -1-i=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{5\pi i}{4}} 
$$
so, substituting  this two values in $(z+i)^3$ and taking all the third-roots we find:
$$
z+i=\sqrt[6]{2}e^{(\frac{3}{4}+2k)\frac{\pi}{3}i} \qquad z+i=\sqrt[6]{2}e^{(\frac{5}{4}+2k)\frac{\pi}{3}i}
$$

that, for $k\in \{0,1,2\}$ gives $2\times 3$ different values of $z+i$, and from these we find the six values of $z$.