# How to solve $\sqrt{2}\cdot(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)^{71}$ by hand?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

How to solve $\sqrt{2}\cdot(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)^{71}$ by hand?

Unfortunately I have no idea how to work through that task. Is there any technique for that?

My solution book says that $1+i$ is the correct solution.

Comment: Use polar form.

Comment: Do you know De Moivre's Theorem?

Comment: Try $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i)^n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4$

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg, no I do not know De Moivre's Theorem

Comment: @jublikon Then the only way is binomial theorem.

Comment: @A---B: Augh, no! Exponentiation by squaring is _much_ cleaner here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even directly:

$$\sqrt2\left(\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt2}i\right)^{71}=\frac1{2^{35}}\left(1-i\right)^{71}$$

and now:

$$(1-i)^2=-2i\implies(1-i)^4=(-2i)^2=-4\implies(1-i)^{68}=\left[(1-i)^4\right]^{17}=-4^{17}\implies$$

$$(1-i)^{71}=-4^{17}(-2i)(1-i)=-4^{17}(-2-2i)=2^{35}+2^{35}i$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), $$\dfrac1{\sqrt2}-\dfrac i{\sqrt2}=\cos\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)+i\sin\left(-\dfrac\pi4\right)=e^{-i\pi/4}$$ by [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t)

Answer (score 1):

One way of going about this would be to convert to polar coordinates: [**recall that we have**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $re^{i \theta} = r(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))$.  Igoring the factored-out $\sqrt{2}$ for now, you can check that we have $r=1$ ($r$ being the [modulus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexModulus.html) of the complex number inside the parentheses).  Therefore, we just need to find a $\theta$ such that $\cos(\theta) = 1/\sqrt{2}$ and $\sin(\theta) = -1/\sqrt{2}$.

After you've made the conversion, notice how much easier it is to compute powers of $e^{i \theta}$.  When you're finished exponentiating, you can convert back to rectangular coordinates if desired, multiplying the result by the previously-ignored $\sqrt{2}$ to finish up.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be that much of a mess to me. Square the base three times and you end at $1$ ...

Comment: You're right @HenningMakholm.  I guess what I mean to say is that, in general, exponentiating things of the form $(x + iy)$ has a high likelihood of being a mess.  I admit I didn't consider this specific case first because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Without De Moivre or polar coordinates: Note that by direct computation, $$\Bigl(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}-\tfrac1{\sqrt2}i\Bigr)^2 = -i $$
so
$$\left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}-\tfrac1{\sqrt2}i\right)^{71} = \left(\tfrac1{\sqrt2}-\tfrac1{\sqrt2}i\right)(-i)^{35}  $$
and then $(-i)^2 = -1$ so
$$ (-i)^{35} = -i\cdot (-1)^{17} = i $$

(This is just what you get from carrying out [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) by hand).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Above expression is $\sqrt2 .e^{-\frac{71\pi \iota}{4}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to convert the complex number in brackets in its polar form:
$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i) = re^{i \theta}$$
where $\sqrt{ (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + (- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2} = 1$ and $\theta = 7 \pi /4$, i.e on the line $f(x) = -x$. Thus the original expression becomes
$$\sqrt{2}(e^{i 7 \theta / 4})^{71} $$ 
or 
$$\sqrt{2}(e^{i 497 \theta / 4}) $$ 
Then you can simply compute $e^{i 497 \theta /4} = \cos(497 \theta /4) + i \sin(497 \theta /4)$ and get your answer.

Edit: if you want a final answer by hand you can break down the exponent 497/4 so that it's easier to compute the sine and cosine.