# Explain me the formula of the inverse of a complex number, or how does $\frac{1}{\rho \cdot cis(\theta)}$ become $\frac{1}{\rho}\cdot cis(-\theta)$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

My book states that:

> The inverse of a complex number $z = \rho \cdot cis \theta$, not zero,
>   is a complex number $\color{red}{\text{$\frac{1}{z}= \frac{1}{\rho}\cdot cis(-\theta)$}}$.

I don't understand the red part. I tried:

$$\frac{1}{\rho \cdot cis(\theta)} = \frac{1}{\rho \cdot (\cos \theta+i\sin\theta)} = \frac{1}{\rho}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos \theta+i\sin\theta} = ???$$

What happens next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)=\text{cis}(x)$ makes this clearer. (This can be proven with taylor series). Then if $z=\rho e^{ix}$, we have $z^{-1}=\rho^{-1}e^{-ix}=\rho^{-1}\text{cis}(-x)$.

To see this directly though, we have $$\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{1}{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{1}{\cos(x)+i\sin(x)}\frac{\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}=\frac{\cos(x)-i\sin(x)}{\rho}$$

Comment: Could you explain that identity?

Comment: Oh nevermind I got it. Thanks

Comment: There are numerous proofs already on stackexhange. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t for example.

Answer (score 1):

We have 
$$
\frac 1{\operatorname{cis}(\theta)} = \frac{1}{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta} = 
\frac{1}{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta} \cdot \frac{\cos \theta - i \sin \theta}{\cos \theta - i \sin \theta}\\ = 
\frac{\cos \theta - i \sin \theta}{\cos^2 \theta - i^2 \sin^2 \theta} = 
\frac{\cos \theta - i \sin \theta}{\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta} \\
= 
\frac{\cos \theta - i \sin \theta}{1} = \operatorname{cis}(-\theta)
$$