# Finding roots in Polar representation of complex number with powers

Tags: polar-coordinates

$(2Z+1)^6 =  -1$

I have tried:

\begin{align}W^6 &= -1\\
&= e^{(pai/2+2pai*k)/6}\\
K &= {0..5}\end{align}

And I got 6 answers.
What to do now?

Comment: The editing process has been lost here. Could someone please edit the question appropriately. I can edit, but I'm unsure what the OP is looking for, especially with regards to "2*_+1" - i can guess but this is insufficient when editing questions, which I believe Lioness99a has done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(2z+1)^6=-1=e^{(2m+1)i\pi}$$ where $m$  is any integer

$$2z+1=e^{(2m+1)i\pi/6}$$ where $m\equiv0,1,2,3,4,5\pmod6$

Now use $e^{2iy}-1=\cos2y+i\sin2y-1=-2\sin^2y+2i\sin y\cos y=2i\sin y(\cos y+i\sin y)$

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer..

Comment: Can you explain again the Now use $e^{2iy}-1=\cos2y+i\sin2y-1=-2\sin^2y+2i\sin y\cos y=2i\sin y(\cos y+i\sin y)$

Comment: @Fayubla, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t