# I have to find $\arg(z)$ of $5e^{-i\frac{3\pi}2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

Can anyone help me find $\arg(z)$ of $5e^{-i\frac{3\pi}2}$ ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you familiar with the form $z = |z|e^{i\arg z}$?

Comment: No, I don't think so

Comment: @Caroline Where did you find this question ? I see that you don't have any idea about exponential form of complex numbers.

Comment: Its a school project - so maybe I have learned it, but just can't remember :-)

Comment: Then, you may need to google it. Once you know it, the question is pretty much straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following GeorgeCoote's comment:

$$z=|z|\exp(i\arg z),$$

in which $0\leq\arg z< 2\pi$.

Your expression is $z=5\exp(-i\frac{3}{2}\pi)=5\exp\left[i(-\frac{3}{2}\pi)\right]=5\exp\left[i(-\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k)\right]$.

You would get $\arg z= -3/2\pi +2\pi k$ for $k=1$ the value is between $0$ and $2\pi$ hence $\arg z = -3/2\pi +2\pi=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Using  [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t),

$$5e^{-3i\pi/2}=5\cos\left(-\dfrac{3\pi}2\right)+i\cdot5\sin\left(-\dfrac{3\pi}2\right)=5i\sin\left(-2\pi+\dfrac\pi2\right)=5i$$

Now use the [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) of atan$2(y,x)$

Comment: is it then + Pi/2?