# Smallest positive integer N power of a exponential complex number such that it is real.

Tags: complex-numbers

How would I find the smallest positive integer N such that $ (w)^N $ is a real number?

Given that

$$w = 8e^{\dfrac{i7\pi}{6}}.$$

Comment: Hint. Start computing some powers and remember the value of $e^{i\pi}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $w = 8e^{i7 {\pi} /6}$. Use an identity which says $e^{i {\theta}} = cos {\theta} + isin {\theta}$. So sin and cos are real valued for reals. So we have to make $sin{N7 {\pi}/6} = 0$. Since $sin {n {\pi}} = 0$ for all n in integers. So make $N7 {\pi}/6$ into an integer and $N \geq 1$ will give $N = 6$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t