# Steps or techniques to prove

Tags: trigonometry

I agree that I have my senior secondary homework assignment to do but I am unable to understand how to proceed on the below question:

> If $2 \cos \theta = x + 1/x$ show that $\cos 2 \theta = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + 1/x^2)$.

How can I prove the required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\cos(2\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1.$$

Comment: Thanks - I was able to solve it easily - thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

$$x^2-2x\cos\theta+1=0$$

$$x=\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta=e^{\pm i\theta}$$
using [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{it}=\cos t +i\sin t$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-eit-cos-t-i-sin-t)

$$x^n=e^{\pm in\theta}\implies x^{-n}=e^{-\mp in\theta}$$

$$x^n+x^{-n}=2\cos n\theta$$ where $n$ is any integer