# Find the value of x such that

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots, quadratics, problem-solving

Find the value of $x$ such that $$\dfrac{(x+\alpha)^n-(x+\beta)^n}{\alpha-\beta} = \dfrac{\sin n\theta}{\sin ^n \theta}$$ when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $t^2 − 2t + 2 = 0$.

Here is my attempt:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I made an attempt https://imgur.com/a/yWVKb

Comment: @Vivek Always include your effort beforehand, else question may get closed and your effort goes in vain.

Comment: @samjoe Ok... Sorry, I didn't know this... I am new here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

WLOG let $\alpha=1+i,\beta+1-i\implies\alpha+\beta=?,\alpha-\beta=?$

Using [How to prove Euler's formula: $e^{i\varphi}=\cos(\varphi) +i*\sin(\varphi)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-to-prove-eulers-formula-ei-varphi-cos-varphi-i-sin-varphi), $$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2i\sin x$$

$$\implies\dfrac{\sin(n\theta)}{\sin^n\theta}=\dfrac1{2i}\cdot\left(\left(\dfrac{e^{i\theta}}{\sin\theta}\right)^n-\left(\dfrac{e^{-i\theta}}{\sin\theta}\right)^n\right)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, Thanks Lab... I really appreciate

Comment: @samjoe, $$1+i+x=\dfrac{e^{i\theta}}{\sin\theta}=\cot\theta+i\iff x=?$$

Comment: @Lab I got this only, but not sure how we get any value for this. Is it only $x=\cot(\theta) - 1$ ? I thought some numerical value was answer!

Comment: @samjoe $x=cot\theta - 1$ is correct

Answer (score 1):

WLOG let $\alpha=1+i,\beta+1-i\implies\alpha+\beta=?,\alpha-\beta=?$

Let $2\cot t=x+\alpha+x+\beta=2(x+1)$

$$(x+\alpha)^n-(x+\beta)^n=\dfrac{2i\sin nt}{\sin^nt}=\dfrac{(\alpha-\beta)\sin nt}{\sin^nt}$$

using [de Moivre's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)

Comment: why have you done this? why are you writing $2\cot t=x+\alpha+x+\beta=2(x+1)$ ?

Comment: @Vivek, So that $x+\alpha, x+\beta$ becomes of the form $$a\pm ib$$

Comment: I am not following you.. $x+\alpha=x+1+i, x+\beta=x+1-i$ which is in the form $x+1\pm i$ so what?

Comment: @Vivek,  Then we can employ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula after replacing $x+1=\cot t$

Comment: Show me how are you using De Moivre's theorem here.

Comment: @Vivek, $$x+\alpha=\cot t-1+1+i=\dfrac{\cos t+i\sin t}{\sin t}$$ right? $$x+\beta=?$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71420/discussion-between-vivek-and-lab-bhattacharjee).

Comment: yes I get it... I wanted to ask, your second solution can't be an independent solution, right? Because you used the answer from first solution that $x=cot(t) -1$ right?

Comment: @Vivek,IMHO, this is independent & more logical. I've used introduced $\cot t$ to utilize de Moivre's theorem

Comment: how did you conclude that $2\cot t=x+\alpha+x+\beta$ ?

Comment: @Vivek, $$\cot t$$ is the arithmetic mean hence equi-distant from both